# Retracting close votes

Tags: support, closing

Recently I have gained enough reputation in order to vote to close certain questions.

Now after clicking the "close" button a tab appears asking me to select the reason to close such and such a question. Say I click "exact duplicate" and then click "vote to close".

1) How can I retract a close vote

2) How can I change the reason I chose to close this question?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't (so far as I know), so try to be sure about it before voting to close. But you can add a comment stating that you've changed your mind, and if the question *does* get closed, you will have the opportunity to vote to reopen.

Comment: This has been resolved. You can now retract your close votes. Yay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to repeat Arturo: right now you can't.

You may want to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ability-to-change-close-reason-before-it-gets-closed). The idea has been floating for a while; considering that it hasn't been implemented yet, I have doubts whether it will be at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.