# Proposal: Discourage questions that are nothing besides a problem statement

Tags: discussion

This is a very clear followup to Qiaochu's question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/proposal-ban-verbatim-homework-questions

The reason that I create a new post is because I want to remove the issue from a homework-related issue to a minimum-quality-standard issue. The current necessary minimum standard for a question on MSE is very low right now. In my opinion, it is too low. Regardless of whether a post originates from a homework set, or someone self-studying, or whatnot, there should be a higher minimum level of effort put into composing the problem.

> I propose that we start downvoting and/or closing questions containing nothing else than the statement of a problem. Further, we should leave a comment explaining why the post was closed and encourage posters to show their work and thought process.

To clarify a little, I would downvote/close posts such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370659/interes-prove-this-equation and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370035/write-the-equation-of-each-of-the-following-use-the-form-y-a-sqrtbx-hk.

In each of these questions, there is nothing besides a problem statement. I do not think that this is okay.

As an aside, I would like to ask that any comments on this question please be on topic.

Comment: If the community decides that something like this is going to be the official policy (and the number of upvotes in Qiaochu's posts suggests that it is quite probable), it would be nice to have a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) tailored for this situation, which would explain why the post was closed and what is the OP expected to do, if he wants to get the question reopened. (It is probably too soon to work on it now, since no decision has been made yet, but it's a thing we should keep in mind.)

Comment: Proposal: ban proposals that ban valid mathematical questions.

Comment: I already do what is being proposed. You're all welcome to join me! Also, I might need a comment template...

Comment: [Are puzzles considered on topic?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-math-puzzle-on-topic-or-off-topic) In this question, the OP specifically asks whether he can post puzzles (without the solution) to see how others solve it. Is this also going to be "banned"?

Comment: @user17762: to quote from the accepted answer to that thread "...and that the post makes it clear that it is posted as a puzzle". Adding a disclaimer of that sort would technically make it no longer a a post containing "nothing else than the statement of a problem."

Comment: @MathGems Feel free to open another thread for your proposal.

Comment: Might I suggest that, rather than banning questions that are nothing but a problem statement, it might be better to specifically require something? Like, maybe a motivation? Anyone asking a question should know why they're asking it, and the least a user can do is fake a reason. Saying "there must be more than just a problem statement" is a little vague, because you could just as easily go "Solve x^2+2x+3=0" and then follow it with a few lyrics from a song (more likely, they might go "I've tried a few integers that didn't work", which satisfies). More specific should be more easily enforced.

Comment: @user17762 How legalistic to we need to be? I'd bet almost all of us can almost always (>90% of the time) tell the difference between a lazy, low-quality problem statement and someone who is posing a puzzle to find different solutions.

Comment: I vote ***not*** to close this post.

Comment: I vote against closing this post.

Comment: @Neal, I agree that lazy questions are [precisely like porn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)...

Comment: @J.M. - perfect

Comment: It deserves mention that the *vast majority* of these type of questions are homework questions, but we do still have questions like [example 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/221152/12952) [example 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/268091/12952) which are good questions despite being flatly stated.  These good questions wouldn't be hard to rephrase to add some detail, and requiring to do so would (imho) be worth the sacrifice if we improved the *overall* quality of the questions on the site.  Not everyone agrees with me on this, though.  I think it would be worth considering ideas for a

Comment: compromise so that we don't isolate these users.  On the other hand, I have no ideas on what we could do to satisfy both parties.  I would be happy to hear suggestions - maybe from the other side?

Comment: I don't think I want all questions like this closed. Sometimes these are the result of the OP simply writing in telegraph style. Sometimes it is from a person who has problems expressing him/herself in English. If it has all the earmarks of a HW problem, sure, but... What J.M. says!

Comment: Which of the current close reasons would be appropriate in this case?  Too localized?  Not a real question?  Neither one quite seems to fit.  (According to [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv), the NARQ close reasons will soon be overhauled.  Once that occurs, perhaps "unclear what you're asking" would make the most sense, since we'll be saying that we can't answer the effectively without more details.)

Comment: I think a good solution to the low-quality questions dilemna is "weighted votes" with weight of the vote cast directly proportional to the reputation of the caster. And the question list based on a threshold of (sum of weights of the votes cast (negative for downvote))/number of votes.
It will solve many other problems of rep inflation too, along with ease of reputation garnering by answering easy questions. (LHF)

Comment: @Jayesh That might work in a system which had a properly designed rep system. But in SE any competent undergrad can easily amass huge rep simply by picking cherries all day long (e.g. calculus questions). So rep has little correlation with expertise needed to judge question quality. Generally, SE rep has little correlation with anything.

Comment: @Jayesh It's a shame there isn't some way to do it based on "tag rep."  I think I should be able to one shot nuke any finite group theory question I feel like, because I can tell what a constitutes a "solve this for me i didn't even read the definition" question looks like in that tag.  But I shouldn't even have a vote on stats or analysis questions.  (This may alleviate MathGems concerns too: said undergrads probably would be the best to judge what calculus questions are or aren't acceptable.)

Comment: @Alex It might help somewhat. But I think the problem is more fundamental, because often knowledge needed to judge "quality" of questions depends on teaching experience (not measured by SE). For example, a teacher might have enough knowledge to know that certain types of exercises are typically difficult in a ring-first (vs. group-first) algebra class. Knowing such, she might be more forgiving of someone who is so stuck that he can't show any reasonable effort (having seen the same in classes when the material was not well-organized). Such domain-specific knowledge plays a crucial role.

Comment: @MathGems But we can "reset" the weights, so that the weights are counted only in the last year or so (Or some similarly long period) Non-active members will see their poower automatically diminish. In any case, we do not just implement the weight system. We can start with assigning everyone a weight of zero and then slowly retroactively assigning weight depending on current factors.

Comment: @Jayesh We can't do anything like that because the SE platform does not provide that functionality.

Comment: @Alexander: *blink* I’m genuinely shocked that any one would claim the right to ‘one shot nuke’ any question. And no, you cannot necessarily tell what constitutes a ‘solve this for me i didn’t even read the definition’ question.

Comment: And again it’s prohibit, prevent, close, downvote, discourage — in short, take a negative approach. I much prefer to encourage better posts and ignore the ones that I don’t like. And quality is a function not just of the question but also of the person reading it. It’s one thing to express one’s negative opinion of a question’s quality by a comment or even a downvote; it’s quite another to preempt someone else’s less negative opinion.

Comment: @Brian That was just hyperbole.  My point was that people with higher scores in a certain tag may have a better idea of what constitutes a 'good' question in that tag.

Comment: @MathGems What is this talk about "teaching". People ask questions because they want to understand something. At least these are the question I think we want. There is no reason to expect teaching skills from the questioner. And it is easy to judge answerers according to whether one learns something or not. MSE is not a tutoring service.

Comment: @Michael Nobody said anything about "teaching skills from the questioner". Please read more carefully.

Comment: @MathGems Of curse nobody wrote that. Which is why I'm confused how teaching experience is related to being a competent voter. I'm tryng to make sense of what you wrote. I still don't get it.

Comment: @Michael: He’s saying that the same *Help, I’m lost!* question might indicate fairly extreme cluelessness from one poster and be quite reasonable from another, depending on the kind of course the poster is taking, and that this may not be at all obvious to a voter who hasn’t some teaching experience with both types of course. And I’ll add that those whose teaching experience has been largely with good students frequently badly misjudge the difficulty of problems for the entire range of students.

Comment: @Alexander: But *good*, even in a particular tag, is a function of both the question and the person reading the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That is all true and well, but I don't see how this relates to voting on questions.

Comment: @Michael I gave an example above: (ring vs. group first algebra courses). Good teachers know *all* the different ways of organizing courses. For each, they know all the significant pedagogical properties, e.g. logical pitfalls, stumbling blocks, common textbook gaps, etc, etc. Because of this, they are in a much better position to judge the innate difficulty of exercises  - in particular, whether or not it is feasible (or even helpful) to attempt to show prior effort.

Comment: @Michael: I’ll let MathGems answer you with regard to his observation, should he choose to do so. As far as mine goes, my teaching experience means that I am far less likely than some to dismiss a *Help, I’m lost!* question or a CP question out of hand as laziness: I’ve seen way too many such questions asked perfectly honestly and seriously in my former school’s Math Tutoring Centre.

Comment: @Michael For an example of  how deeply serious teachers think about the logical structure of their fields, see Pierre Samuel's [Sur l'organisation d'un cours d'arithmetique,](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?6,file=7797,filename=ensmat_1967_13_a_022.pdf) L'Enseignement Mathématique, Vol.13 (1967). This examines all possible ways of organizing the major themes in an elementary number theory course. Such knowledge is typically only obtained with much effort - through many years of teaching such courses, and by serious introspection on the innate logical and pedagogical structure.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I too don't necessarily mind such questions, as long as it ends with the OP giving the extra information needed to help effectively. The reason I support closing such questions is that at the moment, there is a good chance that either a full solution or a collection of random hints will be supplied as an answer before the OP has the chance to supply this information. Such an answer will not necessarily be the best way to help the OP. If it is a full solution, the OP will not learn as much from it as he could. If it consists of random hints then the OP may feel like (cont)

Comment: he ought to understand those hints and should not try to address the other comments until he does (which may not be realistic depending on those hints).

Comment: Better link: P. Samuel, [Sur l'organisation d'un cours d'arithmetique,](http://goo.gl/CWTCa), L'Enseignement Mathématique, Vol.13 (1967). [Pierre Samuel](http://goo.gl/WllOZ) was a Bourbaki member, who, with Zariski, coauthored the very influential two-volume textbook [Commutative Algebra.](http://goo.gl/M8NOc) As Auslander wrote in a [review](http://goo.gl/ERjX0) "It is a pity that there are not more books written by masters of their subject who are as successful as Zariski and Samuel in resisting the temptation of stifling the reader under an undue burden of authoritarianism and slickness."

Comment: @Tobias: You want perfection, and I don’t think that there’s any reasonable way to attain it: it requires placing too many constraints on both askers and answerers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not seeking perfection. I am seeking that people don't post answers they have no way of knowing the helpfulness of, when there are comments asking the OP for reasonable clarifications that would allow them to know that helpfulness.

Comment: @Tobias: I don’t care what you call it, but given the mechanics of MSE, you’re not going to get that without imposing too many constraints.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree with imposing constraints. I disagree with this requiring "too many".

Comment: @Tobias: And I consider constraints that materially interfere with my ability to choose the questions that I consider worth answering to be too many.

Comment: @Tobias Please keep in mind that answers benefit not only the OP. Rather, they benefit all current readers, and also future readers (many of whom may discover the question by web searches). Not too infrequently, some of the most enlightening answers are those to questions which don't constrain the answerer to some approach mentioned by the OP (which are often fruitless, and will certainly be so when cheaters inject nonsensical "prior work" to meet the requirement, so forcing a big waste of time for answerers who earnestly try to debug such nonsense).

Comment: I could not agree more strongly with @Brian's prior remark. The recent large spike of closing on-topic interesting questions will, if continued, force many (most?) good teachers to leave in search of greener pastures, where they don't have to fight for the right to teach mathematics.

Comment: @Math: Or, exactly the opposite; the recent large spike of closing off-topic, uninteresting questions are clearing the way so that good teachers don't have to waste their time looking for opportunities to teach mathematics.

Comment: @MathGems Sorry, I don't read French. I agree that konwing about a topic and teaching it might help in evaluating the effort needed to answer something. But that is actually a good reason why we should make it a requirement for people to supply enough information to judge their background. Something I see very often, is that I cannot answer a question because I simply don't know which equivalent or non-equivalent definition is used.

Comment: @Brian I agree that it is perfectly valid for people to "not even know how to start" and being plain confused. But even in that case, users can supply valid information: The background, the relevant definitions, where the problem comes from etc. I guess if someone asks how to prove that an infinite set in a compact space has an accumuation point, it would be good to know if this is in the context of metric or topologicall spaces and whether compact=compact,T2.

Comment: @Michael: In that example I might ask, or I might simply write an answer that covers the obvious possibilities. I don’t see any good reason to be prevented from doing the latter; a more comprehensive answer might even be more useful in the long run. And if I write an answer based on an erroneous assumption about the context, so what? One of two things happens: nothing, or the OP tells me. In the first case I may have wasted my time, but that’s my choice to make. In the second, I can revise the answer appropriately, and the OP has actually been drawn into the process, which is good.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I’m a good teacher, and I have no trouble finding all sorts of opportunities to teach math here — so many and so easily that I sometimes find it hard to make time to read answers that interest me.

Comment: @Brian: If there are so many interesting answers that you can't keep up, then it would seem to follow that your enjoyment wouldn't be diminished at all if there were fewer questions (so long as it's not too much). And it would likely be increased if the average question quality went up in compensation.

Comment: @Brian: And since you refer to enjoying answers specifically, it is worth considering: is the number of interesting answers controlled primarily by the number of questions that exist, or by the amount of time that answerers have to write answers? If the latter, then decreasing the number of questions would have essentially no effect on the number of interesting answers that appear. (as long as the decrease isn't too extreme)

Comment: @Hurkyl: I do in fact manage to read the answers that I want to read; I just can’t always do it right away. And since I’m more interested in answering than in reading answers, my enjoyment obviously *would* decrease. And it should be clear to you by now that my view of question quality is very different from yours — different enough to make your last sentence false.

Comment: @Brian: Your enjoyment would go down if people asked what you thought were better questions? Really? If the actual content of your disagreement is on what makes for better questions, then you should say that! More importantly, even if you won't budge on your belief that a decrease in volume would hurt your enjoyment of the site, it would allow you admit that it could be mitigated by improved questions, which in turn could lead to cooperatively refining the policy to help ensure that that happens!

Comment: @Hurkyl: I did say that. Please stop wasting my time with silly misinterpretations.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Of course not. This looks like another silly misrepresentation, but on the off chance that you didn’t realize to which comment I was referring, the last sentence in question is *And it would likely be increased ... compensation*. My view of question quality is sufficiently different from yours to make that sentence false (if question quality is judged by you, which in context is how I read it) or irrelevant (if question quality is judged by me, since its hypothesis is likely to be false).

Comment: @Brian: Wonderful. You said something that was silly taken literally, I paraphrased it to what I expected you meant, and you've agreed on my interpretation. So now that we agree that improving question quality can increase a person's enjoyment of using the site, would you be willing to post an answer describing what you are looking for in a question, or even better some sort of refinement to some of the suggestions of what we should be looking for in a question that would make you happier? (Er... I see we've crossed. Are we in agreement?)

Comment: @Hurkyl, what matters to users is, unsurprisingly, overall user experience, not quality of questions.  And in that, there are people who count it as a negative to discourage new users and muzzle potential answerers (e.g., themselves) by closing valid mathematical questions, to see users incessantly propose methods for controlling each other on meta, and to witness the rise of restrictive or authoritarian tendencies presented as "democracy".  To people sensitive to such things, the hypothetical possibility of a marginal increase in question quality would not come close to compensating for that.

Comment: @zyx: "Do my homework for me" is not a valid mathematical question.

Comment: @zyx I prefer you stop doing this. Adhering to the opinion of the (apparent/voting) majority is (IMO) more democratic than ignoring it in the favour of the opinion of the (apparent/voting) minority.

Comment: @Hurkyl, if somebody had posted that as a question you might have a point.  As it is, people post valid mathematical questions, many of which (I assume, as do you) are homework.  There are also a large number of non-cutpaste questions, with displayed effort and all that good stuff, the answering of which would contribute to the doing of someone's homework. If you want to shut down all that homework-doing by third parties you may as well close the site.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, stop what, exactly? Pointing out fallacious meta arguments is on topic (in this case, the idea that question quality, assuming it would actually improve from the point of view of some/all users, is the only relevant consideration).  You might also notice the 25 or so upvotes on the comment consisting of the words "ban proposals that ban valid mathematical questions".  If you think a ratio of perhaps 2 to 1 is sufficient for one group of users to steamroller another, rather than finding the intersection of policies consistent with both groups' preferences, I disagree.

Comment: I wonder how anyone who objects to "(possibly) do my homework for me (if it pleases you)" can live with "do this work by Wednesday next week, or suffer punishment".  It seems to me that the homework posting is far more benign than the homework assignment.  @Hurkyl

Comment: @zyx I have no interest in continuing this discussion here. I have created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8544) in an attempt to create a more fruitful bedding for our arguments. I'll be happy to explain my comment and view there.

Comment: For people with a very uncertain command of English, it may be difficult to describe work done.

Comment: Mathematical problems are, just that, mathematical problems. So I think someone needs to voice much more clearly _exactly_ what kind of extra baggage one is looking for?

Comment: It seems no one knows exactly what a quality question is. Usually mathematicians have the least disagreement among others because they have clear pure axioms and pure logical rules so one can persuade others with true proofs no disputes. What some of posts/comments show, is that MSE has no such axioms, no rules and instead  has  personal opinions somtimes only supported by personal feelings and SE is going on haphazardly. As a result I as a questioner can never be sure if a question is good; because there are no constant rules.SE developers can solve the problem by requiring the sender to tick

Comment: @CutieKrait I don't think it is hard to write questions everyone agree to be good. Locating the exact cutoff value is harder, but asking borderline acceptable question should not be the goal for anyone.

Comment: @ Greinecker Because there's not a clear and complete definition of a an accepted question (accepted by all) (such definition can mostly be implemented by web developer), it is an art to ask such a question. it needs an artistic ability.

Comment: @mixedmath Could you explain why such a question should be banned?

Comment: In my area, public smoking is banned. Well, I see a few people do it daily :P. There are a lot of things banned on SE. Like non-constructive comments. But they still exist. They are promoted. Questions like you say, should ideally not exist. They are just another form of homework questions. But, they still exist, community likes them.

Comment: @MathGems I don't believe we are banning the mathematical questions themselves, just pressing for better asked questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask a homework question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: Can we please stop using references in the meta, then *deleting those references*?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

*The below constitutes an attempt to provide a comment template to accompany down-/close votes. A copy has been placed on [the list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9407).*

---

**This question is of insufficient quality** *(Version 6 -- reflect the new "on hold" status)*

If necessary, this can be preceded by *Hello, welcome to Math.SE*.

> Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

`Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.`

(*Note: The link under "This" (which has been shortened to allow for more text) in the comment template should be updated to point to a to-be-created "Proper question formatting" thread in place of the current one, which only deals with homework questions.*)

---

One thing that I would like to see added to this is a word on what to do once the question has been edited -- so as to make it more probable that indeed the negative votes are removed. Suggestions directed at this are appreciated.

In some sense, I think close votes would be more appropriate for this type of question than downvotes, because they are easier to cancel by arbitrary users (using reopen votes and -requests if necessary). This as opposed to downvotes which are more visibile, and can only be cancelled by the person that cast them.

One thing that certainly would help increase the effectiveness of suggested template is a possibility to revoke close votes; see [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687) and links there for more information.

Following Jyrki Lahtonen's answer, I think it is good to include a word on the intended use of this template. It is *not* intended to be cast in stone, nor is its use. Please, *always* use common sense and your truthful judgement before adding it anywhere. This will help to prevent unnecessary frustration for questioners and the share of people opposing the measures that this template suggests.

---

**Addendum:** After having noticed that the comment character limit prohibits people from including the necessary nuance in their statements, I have created a [QA Policy Discussion chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8544) to circumvent this. All are welcome to share their thoughts to come to a consensus; the only requirements are that one is thoughtful, willing to listen to others, and most importantly, ***polite***.

Comment: It's a good start, but I believe that neither the phrase "copy-pasted from a source" nor the word "homework" should appear in such a comment.  The current discussion is not about _homework_ questions, but only about the desired quality of questions we keep open.  As such, it would be more neutral to simply state that the _quality_ of the question is in dispute (including points such as it is "impossible" to discern what level of answer would benefit the user, or exactly what about the question is troubling the user).   (Likely a "new" _How to ask a good question_ meta-thread should be opened.)

Comment: @Arthur I was indeed a bit bothered by the fact that I was referring to "How to ask a good _homework_ question" when the guidelines set out there seem to apply to a more general type of question; I felt there needed to be a comment to explain this. I'll gladly delete the word _homework_ if the link is replaced by one that indicates guidelines for general questions. Would "is phrased as a stand-alone problem" form an adequate replacement for "cp'ed from a source"?

Comment: I personally don't have a problem with the suggestion from the last sentence.  Perhaps append "...without context" to it?  (As for any links to meta-threads: that can always be fixed in post-production!)

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: That's looking pretty good to me.  Although, I'd suggest "Your question..." $\rightarrow$ "This question..." and to snip "Concretely:".

Comment: I deleted my answer, since it's mostly obsolete now, but I should save this comment:  "There is a special syntax for adding the edit link in comments: [edit], if I remember correctly. So [edit] should be an edit link to this post. – Mad Scientist 53 mins ago"

Comment: @Douglas Thanks again for all of your remarks. As the use of "This" in the snippet is rather ubiquitous, I prefer to leave it at "Your" (though I see where you're coming from since these are "copied" problems). IMO "Concretely" adds a nice emphasis to the most important points made in ref'd meta post. The fact that we're down to single words shows that we're approaching the limit snippet :).

Comment: I would change the template as:

... This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement/) ...

Comment: I really appreciate the time you've been putting into this. I also really like the direction the template is going in.

Comment: If people insist on punishing such questions, I much prefer that they use downvotes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Who is talking of punishing the questions? The proposal is to try to avoid the questions in the first place, and when they do appear, try to get the OP to improve them.

Comment: @Tobias: I thought it clear that *punishing the questions* simply refers to closing them, downvoting them, making them harder to ask, etc., and quite a few people are advocating one or more of those practices.

Comment: @Brian: If *that's* what you're talking about, then why did you use the word "punish" which both connotes and denotes something very different?

Comment: @Hurkyl: Because (a) I thought it obvious in context, and (b) that usage falls well within the range of connotations of the word.

Comment: @Brian: ... and even if you are talking about punishment, rather than simply closing questions pending improvement, note that (assuming noble intent) the point of a punishment is to correct or deter the offending behavior. An ineffectual punishment is a rather terrible thing, as all it does is cause hard feelings without any positive effect.

Comment: @Hurkyl: And from my point of view what you want will cause hard feelings with very little positive effect except possibly for those who will be able to postpone a bit longer having to learn to deal with the increased volume.

Comment: @Brian: I can't work out the antecedents to your pronouns. But anyways, while it is indeed obvious you implicitly meant something like "this policy is a punishment", it's equally clear that Tobias implicitly meant something like "No, I think it's not. If you're going to make such a provocative claim, then you had better justify it".

Comment: @Brian: I've been in favor of this (and stronger) policy from the very beginning. And I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one. The only thing volume has changed is to make ignoring the issue (so as to avoid dealing with this discussion) much less tolerable.

Comment: The most recent variant of the comment template exceeds max comment length when the [edit] link is added.

Comment: @AntonioVargas It already functions as an edit link presently. You don't need to add the link to editing the question, it's there automagically.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a nice feature.  Thanks for telling me, I never would have noticed otherwise `:)`

Comment: "this does not match many users" *preferences* would be better.  The words 'quality standards' are somewhat condescending, ill-defined, and the subject of some disagreement about whether adding the extra material improves a question.  //// Replacing "improvements will" by "changes can" in the last sentence is more neutral and factually correct. //// "make Q more valuable for future visitors" is debatable and can be read as an unnecessary criticism; I suggest to drop it.  Lengthening a question with OP's work+context arguably makes it cruftier and more localized, not of more universal value.

Comment: This is a good start, but I agree with @zyx. It should be more focused and concise. There should also be some indication that the community stands behind the comment, so the question asker doesn't think the user posting it is just being cranky.

Comment: I added this template to the list of templates: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4932#4932

Comment: Some days off, to detach emotion and content. I still consider the "disagreement" on "QS" to be sufficiently dealt with by being preceded with "many users'" ("preferences" does not provide enough incentive to change the question IMO). The part about condescension I simply don't get. Ill-definedness is countered by the rest of the comment. //// Your other two suggestions will be implemented momentarily. Of relevance for the last is the observation I made in the QA chat room yesterday.

Answer (score 37):

Late to join this party, but there are a few sporadic thoughts I want to share, so here comes anyway.

First and foremost I'm all for culling the weakest questions from here. The fact that they irritate many frequent posters is reason enough! Learning how to filter out some tags was a good start that improved my daily experience, but apparently that is not good enough for everyone (for many a reason).

Also I quite like the evolution of this thread, including its title. "Banning questions with no work shown" was IMHO bad. The current title is better, but I still have some reservations. The goal is to improve the quality of the questions, and some criteria have been listed. Some eager beavers have already gotten to work and started reposting comment templates left and right and airing their pet peeves at newcomers.

I want to call for some flexibility in the application of ALL the listed criteria of quality.

1. The ability to formulate mathematical thoughts and questions according to the exacting standards of the tradition of our trade is an integral part of the training of a mathematician. That is, indeed, one of the reasons we the teachers want you undergrad students here to formulate your questions unambiguously. However, we should not expect similar standards from non-math majors. It is not always an essential skill for them, and they simply have not been exposed to good mathematical style enough to be able to phrase their own questions well. Yet they are intelligent people worthy of our respect. Also our Charter/FAQ welcomes their questions also! A computer scientist or an engineer who happens to find him/herself in a cryptography course may write here asking about someting on elementary number theory. They are not always fully conversant with the proper terminology, and may not realize the need to list all the necessary assumptions. Yet their questions should be accepted and answered! Some of you may cry: "We cannot answer an underdefined question!" I say, Tough! Learning to "autocomplete" mathematical questions so that they make sense is another integral skill in our trade! If you cannot autocomplete the question yourself, then ask for help in the comments, and/or wait for somebody else who can make sense out of it to show up. My undergrad measure theory professor started his course by stating that he expects us to correct all the mistakes in the homework problems that he assigns us so that they make sense. Before we solve them. To drive this point home: Imagine that you have graduated, and have taken a job in some company. If your boss assigns you a problem to work on, I hope you have the sense not to reply: "But Sir, as stated, your question is trivial and/or does not make sense."
2. Many seem to think that for a question to be of high quality it should be typeset in beautiful LaTeX. While that is almost a must on some occasions, this strikes me as silly. Do we really teach freshmen to use TeX somewhere? In these parts they have zero use for TeX before they start writing their first practice essays, which typically happens in the Spring of their second year.
3. I would give the askers of more advanced questions some slack. Specialized questions from advanced undergraduate courses give many of us a chance to learn something ourselves and/or refresh a piece of theory that was half-covered by cobweb in some corner of our brains. Of course, it is not impossible that a student taking an algebraic geometry course is equally lazy as that freshman in a calculus course, but usually they have learned at that point. Also at that level we have more askers in self-study mode (may be somebody at an institute were no local help is available).
4. This is an international site meaning that you should not always judge askers by your local standards. Everyone here is very understanding of the occasional language mistakes we the furriners commit (thank you!). But there are other factors. If you are studying a textbook written in English, writing out the question is usually easy, but language may form an extra obstacle when trying to describe your own work. Another related thing is that the role of homework problems in grading varies from one region to another. I don't remember what kind of an impact to your grade the HW problems have in the US, but in my courses it goes as follows. In order to earn the right to take the final exam the students must do some minimum number of homework problems. If they do more than the minimum, it will affect their grade, but the effect is minimal, say, up to 5% of the total grade (IOW it is meaningful only in borderline cases). They still copy solutions from pals and such, but learn after a year or two that this won't help them in the finals. This may explain why I am less worried about "cheaters" than some other members. If the cheating aspect is for real, then by all means we should do something about it, my reservations notwithstanding.

But my items #1 and #3 lead me to think that a degree of some extra maturity is required from anyone littering the threads with comment templates calling for some obscure quality standards in the name of the holy Math.SE. Yes, in most of the cases we are talking about it will be obvious that the asker is just logging on to a free do-my-homework-for-me service. But there are cases when more experience is needed (even though the question may look like a botched elementary HW problem). I might want to forbid undergrads from taking action in some cases, quite irrespective of their rep tally, except that it is not politically correct here. So instead I will ask you all to also be aware of your own limitations. I have made such mistakes here myself, so I will testify that it is not easy to diagnose that you really don't know what the question is about even though you initially thought that you should (thinking that if you don't then there's something wrong with the question).

Last (tongue-in-cheek, or may be not). Why do we complain so much about the copy/paste homework problems? I mean, is there a qualitative difference between a copy/paste homework problem and a copy/paste textbook answer? Both are largely relying on somebody else's work to produce the goods. Cousins of CPTA are "Let me google it for ya" - answers. Guilty as charged! But aren't the askers really looking for something they cannot get from their textbooks and/or Wikipedia?

Comment: +1. I agree with all the points.

Comment: Mostly agreed. As one of the alleged "litterers" I would like to emphasize that I try to judge how apt the comment template is before I put it under a question (broadly following conditions like 1 and 3 above). I'll try to increase my efforts in this regard, and I hope the other users of the template (or derivatives of it, I've seen some) will also be thoughtful.

Comment: Well put, Lord_Farin. I'm not pointing fingers at any particular "litterers". I have just seen some instances I didn't agree with. It is also easy to miss that a question has been improved/edited - possibly as a response to such a comment - so my reaction is also sometimes misguided! As long as we judge the questions case-by-case we will do fine I think. This is NOT a job for an automaton.

Comment: I agree with all of these points.

Answer (score 18):

> I propose that we start downvoting and/or closing questions containing
>   nothing else than the statement of a problem. Further, we should leave
>   a comment explaining why the post was closed and encourage posters to
>   show their work and thought process.

If I look at [questions with the most views, answers, and votes this month](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=month), then I see a lot of questions that may be closed according to these standards:

- 3rd [How can I prove that $xy\leq x^2+y^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2)

  > How can I prove that $xy\leq x^2+y^2$?
- 7th [Do factorials really grow faster than exponential functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351815/do-factorials-really-grow-faster-than-exponential-functions)

  > Having trouble understanding this. Is there anyway to prove it?
- 8th [Is $2^{218!} +1$ prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357037/is-2218-1-prime)

  > Prove that $2^{218!} +1$ is not prime.
  >
  > I can prove that the last digit of this number is $7$, and that's all.
  >
  > Thank you.
- 27th    [Let $A^{27}=A^{64}=I$, show that $A=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353110/let-a27-a64-i-show-that-a-i)

  > Let $A$ be a square matrix, $A^{27}=A^{64}=I$,
  >   show that $A=I$
- 49th    [Prove that $4x-x^4 \leq 3, x \in \Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361118/prove-that-4x-x4-leq-3-x-in-bbb-r)

  > How can I tackle the following inequality :
  >
  > > Prove that $4x-x^4 \leq 3$, where $x$  is any real number.
  >
  > Can someone point me in the right direction?

I think there around 5-10 questions in the top 50 most popular questions of the month, that should be closed with these "new" closure standards.

I don't think those question self are great. But with closing such a question, you are also closing the (potential) great answers.  Instead of closing, I think a more decent way would be to put such questions [on hold](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/discussion-what-should-we-do-about-the-increasing-number-of-questions/9207#9207).

Comment: They are not that great. Some gave rise to good answers. I don't think tey would all magically disappear. Some will be rewritten to confirm to higer standards, some will not. No reason to worry.

Comment: I hope you realise that closing questions is exactly the manner in which we "put such questions on hold".  When a question is closed, it is an indication that there is something not quite right with the question as posed, but the querent (and others) always has the option of editing the question to make it more acceptable.  We even have an [entire meta-thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6424/8348) devoted to soliciting _reopen_ votes!

Comment: @ArthurFischer Quoting Kundor, who proposed this idea:

"It should have friendlier connotations ("Your question is worthwhile, but here's some things we want you to do before we look at it") than closure does."

Comment: It's probably just me, but I wouldn't feel the slightest loss if none of them got any answer.

Comment: @Martin It probably is not just you. But these are all in the top 50 most popular questions of the month. So in general, people on MSE did like it that these question got an answer. I think the reason my post here got so many downvotes is because the audience on this meta doesn't represent the audience on MSE very well. To me it feels a little bit like the elite is going to determine which questions they want to see at MSE.

Comment: @Kasper The minimum reputation for upvoting is 15. I'm not sure this is enough for voting to represent te actual stakeholders in MSE.

Comment: It's interesting to compare your [first example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2) with [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349940/if-x-neq-0-y-neq-0-then-x2xyy2-is/)

Comment: I highly doubt that Kundor's "hold" functionality will ever be implemented.  Furthermore, we shouldn't base solutions to current problems on features that do not currently — and may not ever — exist.  While certain users may leave in a huff over their questions being closed, others (the more thoughtful variety, IMHO) should read a comment such as the one proposed in Lord_Farin's answer as a mini-guide to the desired etiquette of math.SE.

Comment: Closing is the correct way to put a question on hold, and [SE is even thinking about changing the language to make it clearer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d). There are quite a lot of changes planned to closing, I don't see how an additional "on hold" feature would be needed.

Comment: @ArthurFischer If I read the link of Mad Scientist, I think there is a very good chance that "closed" will be replaced at all SE's with something like "on hold" or "Answering is disabled until this question is improved".

Comment: Changing what something is called is not the same as replacing the functionality.  I still highly doubt that the functionality that Kundor envisions (a single "on hold" vote puts a question on hold, and _any_ edit to a question on hold takes it off hold) will ever be implemented.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I actually agree with you, the reason I liked Kundor's idea is not because of changing the functionality dramatically, but because, quoting Jaydles: *It [getting you question closed] is a little like having someone respond to a proposal you wrote with:

REJECTED*

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think you should address your concern at the post from [lord farin](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-ban-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement/9202#9202) .  I'm actually arguing the same thing as you do in this post.

Comment: @Kasper: Sorry (again) :-/

Comment: Of course there will be lots of people who like these questions. There are lots of students who like to get answers without working at all. Chances are there is a fair overlap between these two groups, and at some point I think it's fair to ask whether facilitating this behaviour is conducive to the general state of education, which I believe is the duty of every educated person.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker [*Some will be rewritten to confirm to higer standards, some will not. No reason to worry.*]
[This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94441/what-is-the-kolmogorov-extension-theorem-good-for) of yours shows no effort.
Would you not mind if it was closed?

Comment: @MakotoKato ?!?!?! I guess you have no idea what effort means. My motivation may suck, but it is certainly explicit.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker You show no effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @MakotoKato Sorry but you are clearly out of your depth here. If you want to slander Michael, at least do so using a question on a mathematical subject you know something about.

Comment: @Did I just said his question shows no effort to solve the problem. Is my observation wrong?

Comment: @MakotoKato Yes you are wrong.

Comment: @Did Could you explain what effort it shows to solve the problem?

Comment: @MakotoKato No, since (1) this is apparent to anybody interested in the matter and (2) experience shows that you are actually not interested in explanations. You tried to slander Greinecker because you thought this might allow you to push your specific agenda and you failed, time to move on.

Comment: @Did [*You tried to slander Greinecker because you thought this might allow you to push your specific agenda and you failed, time to move on.*]
I did not slander him. I just stated the fact that his question does not show effort to slove the problem. By the way, why did you vote to delete my answer in this thread?

Comment: @MakotoKato Read my lips: `time to move on`. (And repeating as a mantra that the question shows no effort will not make this true.)

Comment: In reading the post by Michael Greinecker there is no attempt shown to solve himself. I have absolutely no problem with that, as the entire point of being on this site is to seek help from people smarter or more studied than we are. But, the point that @Did is making is completely valid. The very general concept of the OP is that we should reject questions that do not show effort by the poster to solve themselves. I understand that there is a big difference between Michael Greinecker's post & simpler ones, but that's why the point itself needs to be less general.

Answer (score 13):

Originally from [Hurkyl](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9367/no-offense-intended-but#comment34067_9367),

---

To get help from your professor, you should walk into his office, place your homework sheet in front of him, and silently wait for him to give you the answer.

Disrupted, the professor picks up your homework and notices that it is relatively untouched, save for your name on the top. From above the paper line, you see him give you a strange glance.

"Well..." he starts, giving you a prompting gesture.

"Well, could you help me with the problems?" you respond.

"Hm, do you want me to do your homework for you?"

"Well, no, I just want some help with them."

"...and what have you tried?" he asks, setting the homework sheet back down.

"I have no idea where to start."

"Then can I see your notes?"

"Uh... no, I left them at home."

"Well," he says, handing you back your papers, "I suggest you come back tomorrow with those notes."

Frustrated, you get up. You are about to leave when you hear the professor call you again.

"Oh, and I'd suggest you come back having attempted some of the problems too."

Comment: Except that, the only problem is that it is easy to return to the professor than to reopen a closed question.

Comment: @A---B Well, the professor has an obligation and gets paid for this kind of stuff, but we don't. (Btw, aren't you forgetting a particular chat meet up?)

Comment: True to some degree. (Sadly I did not receive the ping about the chat.)

Comment: (Hard to ping someone who doesn't show up lol)

Comment: (Arguable but true).

Comment: @A---B It may be easy to return to the professor. It is easy to reopen a closed question.

Comment: @Did Can you give me some examples of questions from < 100 rep users that were closed  and reopened ?

Comment: @A---B Not sure about < 100 rep (nor how it relates), but see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626025/272831), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2330016/272831), and some stuff [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19042/272831).

Comment: @A---B You seem to think it is difficult to reopen a closed question. Given the mechanisms devoted exactly to this operation, I am surprised.

Answer (score 9):

We will see how this works in reality, but one of the possible
drawbacks of this proposal my be an increase on workload on the
users.

Ideally, if a question containing only problem statement is
posted, then:

- The questions is closed with a comment what can be improved. (5 users are of [reputation at least 3000](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges) are needed for this; it make take some time from them, since the decision is not always clear-cut. Sometimes this might lead to a longer discussion in comments whether the question should really be closed or not.) And perhaps before closing on this ground we should also search for duplicates; which also requires work. (But we are supposed to do this with new questions anyway, regardless of this proposal.)
- The OP writes an improved version.
- If the improvement does not seem sufficient, some of more
  experienced users leave comments what else can be improved.
- If the edited post looks good, someone posts a reopen
  suggestion on meta and we again need 5 users (with rep$\ge$3000)
  to do this.

It is always possible that only a fraction of the questions will
be improved, so maybe usually only 5 people who vote to close the
question will be needed; which is not that bad.

(But I have to admit that I do not have a better solution that the
one already proposed; so even if there are some downsides to it,
it still might be the best way to go.)

Answer (score 6):

Be careful what you wish for.
Have you thought *well* about possible implications of your proposal?
Here are some I came up with.

(1) There are great many good questions containing nothing else than the statement of a problem.
Under your proposed rule, all of them should be closed.

(2) You are actually demanding a question to be personalized or localized.
Let us take for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232526/is-g-pg-is-a-p-group). You are demanding that he tell us which part of the *particular proof* he doesn't understand. Suppose you tell him how he can complete his proof along his line and he accepts your answer. The case is closed and we miss all the other different(and possibly better) proofs each of which has its own merit.

(3) A mathematically mature user may not like to explain how he tried to solve a problem, because he knows that there are various approaches to it.
When his question is closed under your rule, he might well be offended and leave the site.
In the end, this site might be full of homework-type questions explaining where they stuck.

Comment: Regarding your point (3): I fail to understand why anyone would want to not share their progress, purely because there might be a different way to approach it. Regarding point (2): When the OP marks an answer as accepted, that doesn't prevent people from still answering the question. Regarding point (1): Just because a question contains good mathematics doesn't make it a good question. Routinely, there are mathematically interesting questions that are very difficult to answer satisfactorily because the asker has left out critical information about background and available tools.

Comment: I also don't see how the linked question is related to the point you make in (2). The asker has mentioned their efforts and has a (very) partial idea of how to proceed with a proof - I don't think anyone is suggesting that questions like this be closed. (And there's no particular proof he mentions - his point is that he *doesn't* know a proof).

Comment: @T.Bongers [*Regarding your point (3): I fail to understand why anyone would want to not share their progress, purely because there might be a different way to approach it.*]
Because explaining how one tries to solve a mathemetical problem and where he is stuck and
asking help along his line are personal and localized.

Comment: @MakotoKato not that it matters: *"When I was a new member of this site, I didn't much care about my reps. But I changed my mind after I noticed what I said above."*

Originally you said that you didn't care about rep when you was new(hence when you had low rep), now you do care(as of a few months ago) and you had high rep then and now.

Now you are saying the exact opposite thing. Low you cared, high you don't.

That being said, (+1) to this answer, I do agree mainly with point (2).

Comment: The comments were deleted simultaneous to my comment...?? Moderator?

Comment: @DisplayName [*Now you are saying the exact opposite thing.*]
No, I am not.
I realized (when I had low reps) that a low rep user has various disadvantages.
So I changed my mind.
Understood?

Comment: @MakotoKatob I suppose it really depends on your definition(range of time) of 'new user'. So you do or don't care about reps? You just implied that you do, but above(deleted now), you said that you didn't, hence Asaf(?) called you out on it.

Comment: @DisplayName Let A be the time when I registered in this site.
Let B be the time when I realized that a low rep user has various disadvantages.
Let C be the time when I gained rather high reps, say 10,000.
During the period between A and B, I didn't care about my reps.
During the period between B and C, I did care about my reps.
During the period between C and the present time I don't care about my reps.
Understood?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that some posters counter the comment-template with a question-templates: copy-pasted text in which a problem statement is wrapped. One example (seen in multiple posts to which I do not link)

> I want to solve the example below, but I can not.
>
> [*Problem statement goes here.*]
>
> Please, you will be very grateful if someone would help resolve the communities in this example. Previously thank you.

I don't think that the addition of such a wrapper achieves anything in terms of question quality. Presumably, one could ignore the wrapper and demand more original text from the poster. Considering the language barrier, I don't think that would lead very far.

#### So here comes yet another proposal.

> *Tag* questions that are nothing besides a problem statement as `problem-statement`.

And a few bullet points:

- The  standard phrases such as "I can't solve this", "How to solve this", "I need help", "Help please", "Thank you in advance" should not be a factor in whether a question qualifies as `problem-statement`.
- The tag could be applied by anyone with privilege to retag questions, including the OP of course. Whether a post is a `problem-statement` can be objectively determined; in this the proposed tag is different from `homework`.
- The tag wiki should encourage the poster to provide the source of the problem, possibly mentioning potential copyright issues.
- One could object that `problem-statement` is a meta tag which are [discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). But it actually does describe the *content* of the post. It is less "meta" than the existing `homework` tag. And it seems that for many users `problem-statement` tag would be useful in deciding whether to engage with the question.

Comment: Note the first comment at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/ suggesting to do everything that one might want to do with policies, with tags instead.  I don't care for the idea of using it to accelerate question closings, but it would have the benefit of making it *visible* how many questions of this type there are, and how many are closed.  It is also consistent with both the pro- and anti-closing positions to add more tags and use them to improve reading and filtering, including finding questions to close or reopen.

Comment: I agree with the first half of your answer: wrapping the question in a wrapper does nothing to improve question quality.  However, dealing with this by introducing a "meta tag" does not seem like a good solution.  SE generally frowns on "meta tags", as past experience has shown they lead to problems: disputes, editing wars.  Tags are meant to help people use search to find related problems, not as a punishment.  (Also, original posters aren't going to know to mark their question with a `problem-statement` tag.)  And even if others add the tag, it's not clear how the tag itself will help.