# No offense intended, but...

Tags: discussion, etiquette, community

I haven't been a member on here for all that long of a period of time, but I would like to point out some things that I have observed that some may be overlooking. I have visited the site a large number of times before joining I would like to mention as well.

First of all, from the comments to most of the posts I have seen over the last couple of days on meta, nobody really wants to see anything from anyone new on MSE.  Some are belligerent about it while a few others are perhaps less aware of their attitude, but it exists.  I came here because I was already in the stack exchange community, a cross affiliation from my time I spend working with Ubuntu.
I am also an applied math major and at my school that means taking grad classes regularly, so I'm not that far down the totem pole in that respect either.  There seems to be alot of bitterness, especially regarding the homework problems situation.  While I understand that many people may be looking for a handout it is unfair to assume that is the case for anybody asking a homework question, or help understanding or clarifying some aspect of a particular area.  Some people do make an effort, just saying.
Call me crazy, but I kinda feel unwanted here, and I may be, in which case I will gladly leave.  MSE should be as much about camaraderie as about solving particular problems.  I have seen many of my own friendships grow with peers as we explore some particular problem together.  I would suggest that perhaps as a community, more "communing" could be done.
Anyways, if you read this far thanks, hope you'll consider what I've said if you've unfairly been a jerk to someone who didn't deserve it recently.

Comment: Your observation about "alot of bitterness" is correct. This is a function of time, so there's hope it reached its maximum already and will decay over time. ¶ I don't see why you personally feel unwanted, though. Clicking through to your main site activity, I found one question, which already had an upvote from me and was in my "favorites". (I tend to mark questions as favorites and then hope someone else answers... I'm lazy like that.)

Comment: It was nothing directed at me personally to which I was referring but I've read dozens of the meta posts over the last couple days to gain these impressions.  As I said as well, it surely isn't everybody, but those who hold those opinions seem to make sure their voices are heard quite often.

Comment: It is basic etiquette all over the world that when a stranger asks you a question, the reply should begin with some variation on the words "what have you tried?", "is this homework?", "what are *your* thoughts?", CLOSED, "do your own work", "you have not met our quality standards", or "mend your ways or don't come back".  People on MSE sometimes forget that. If only those greetings were used more often, I think everyone could feel right at home.

Comment: And, of course, to get help from your professor, you should walk into his office, place your homework sheet in front of him, and silently wait for him to give you the answer.

Comment: @zyx Do you know the feeling when you are at a party, nipping beer and a stranger approaches you and says to you "Prove that every continuous function from the closed unit interval to the reals is uniformly continuous." What do you do in these situations?

Comment: I have no problem with people asking OPs "what have you tried". I just wish they would do this more politely! (I find copied-and-pasted comment rude, but it is better than just silently closing the question...)

Comment: I should also say that I regularly recommend my students to ask their question here. They do not want to because they see the community as too snobbish. I think we have a problem...

Comment: In particular, the "does not meet our quality standards" comment makes me shudder, partly because of the bureaucratese, but mainly because it could be interpreted as speaking for me.

Comment: @user1729 That does sound like a problem. Here's a possible fix: suggest that they *answer* 2-3 questions before posting their first question. Nobody tells WHYT to answerers, and in the process they will get used to the site and also get rid of the rep=1 indicator. Answering questions here may be more useful anyway. ¶ #Tristen: Since your profile says "send me a line", I'll point out that SE sites have no direct messaging feature, and the email address you entered is not shown to other users. So, if no SE users ever contact  you directly, it's not necessarily because they are antisocial.

Comment: @user75064 I shouldn't have to tell them some way of getting around the site being unwelcome to them!

Comment: @user1729 If the site currently appears to be unwelcome to certain style of questions, one can try to change the existing users, or change the style of posting questions... I agree there should be kinder, gentler guidance, for example [of this kind](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8720/75064). ¶ At the same time, if someone feels that Math.SE is not for them, they just might be right. No site is a good fit for everyone; for example I don't participate in MO. (Mostly because I find it boring, but it's possible that there's a touch of "see the community as too snobbish" in it as well.)

Comment: @user75064 To these students it is not that the site appears unwelcoming to a certain style of question, but rather unwelcoming *in general*, perhaps because of the response to this style of question.

Comment: @user1729: I see your problem. But this is the way internet forums work. Whichever forum you join, you are well advised to lurk for a little while.  Then you will learn about "house rules" and about the way the regulars post. If you just "crash the party", you may easily cross a few lines, and it makes sense that the regulars will let you know about your faux pas! I know that there are many "anything goes" chat forums in the web, but Math.SE is not one of those. I kind of like it that way.

Comment: I think MSE is better and has less bitterness than stackoverflow and physics SE and many other american forums like daniweb.com in which (sometimes unwritten) rules are construed bitterly (specially on new users). In MSE there are people that never downvoted. I think almost all populated english forums have more bitterness than forums with less users.

Comment: Something to be noted is the review system on new user posts. It attracts high rep people's attention to new user posts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I understand this, and I too like the rigid structure of MSE. I initially was surprised when my students told me that they were afraid to come here, but when I thought about it a bit more then I began to understand why. I do not think the structure is the problem. Personally, I think the site is too harsh to those coming here. My view of MSE is of a lecturer's or professor's office hours. In such situations the student has obligations *but so does the professor*. They should be polite and helpful, and so on...(cont.)

Comment: ...and I wonder if MSE comes across as the professor who is unwilling to answer questions unless they are of a sufficient difficulty, or the professor who is constantly looking down his nose at students...I dunno. I cannot quite put my finger on anything specific, but taking a step back I think I can understand my students fears and reservations about this site.

Comment: The difference is that when visiting a professor's office, you know who's gonna answer. Here it may be one of the bullies among upper classmen looking for his breakfast victim. I don't know the ideal way of resolving this, and my own feelings about this are continuously swinging. The resentment towards copy/pasted questions is genuine. May be it is also about fear? Fear of the site that was once largely populated by people taking math seriously becoming overrun by a horde. More advanced questions getting buried under the pile of calculus questions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen On the subject of fear, our Founding Father spake thus: "Fear is underrated as a design element. You know what site lets people post fearlessly, 100% of the time? Yahoo Answers." [Source](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/296358032579911681). ¶ Personally, I have nothing to fear from calculus questions (except fear itself?), knowing  that I can get [50 recent unanswered questions with my favorite tags](http://stackexchange.com/filters/89000/favorite-tags?sort=noanswers) anytime I want, no matter how much hw is posted here.

Comment: @Jyrki: We have nothing to fear, but running out of beer! (F.D. Roosevelt's Head)

Comment: @Jyrki: I have no trouble finding more questions that interest me and require non-trivial effort than I have time to think about — and being retired, I’ve lots of time to think about them.

Comment: @André: I’ve taken to keeping open a boilerplate countercomment.

Comment: @Michael: Faint in shock. Probably have a lovely conversation when I come to. And whatever else it may be, MSE is not a party (though with luck I may have a beer in hand).

Comment: Don't get me wrong! My enjoyment of the site went up when I learned to filter out uninteresting tags, so I don't have problems finding interesting questions. But I am worried about some other regulars. I am still trying to put my finger on what exactly it is about these HW questions that bothers them (and to some extent also me). I probably will advice my calculus students to take a look at this site (next fall I will have a batch of freshmen to tend to). But I will also advice them to lurk a while first. I don't expect many to come, as many of them will find doing math in English too much.

Comment: ...and I still have some Talisker left. Sláinte!

Comment: One difference between @Hurkyl's professor analogy and my comment preceding it is that the behavior I described can and frequently does occur on MSE, while the elements of the professor story *cannot* happen here.  Nobody is conducting an office hours or under any requirement to respond to the people asking questions.  I would like to know, though, what would happen to non-tenured faculty who answer many questions at office hours by closing the door in the student's face, or saying "it does not meet our standards", "come back later after doing your work", or other MSE-style responses.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, have you ever been to a party at a large mathematics department?  There usually really are some people who do essentially what you describe, and more people who in less overt ways make the party into a form of work.  The difference is that on MSE it takes one second to walk away, and at the math party, you are cornered.  Enjoy the beer, at least...

Comment: @zyx No I haven't. It seems they made a wise choice on MO when they made their norms correspond to seminars and not parties.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, MO doesn't have norms, it has preference for an in-group and standards applied mostly only to the out-group.  The questions are not judged on their own merit, but also on who posts them, and some of the most popular questions with the best answers have been "low-effort questions" by MSE (proposed) definitions.  As an example see Elencwajg's query on proving that Riemann surfaces have non-free fundamental group.  The professor you mentioned earlier was the only one with a consistent standard: he said it should be closed.  Luckily, it was not.

Comment: @zyx I'm aware of that. I was referring to the FAQ there. But I don't find MO that unwelcoming and I'm a mere economist.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, of course a site for academics in one field will be welcoming to those from another.  This is not the MSE situation where professors mingle with 15 year olds having trouble in basic math classes.  If the user population on MSE all had doctorates we would not be having this conversation.

Comment: @zyx Faculty are obliged to help their students; they are paid for it. SE network has no obligation to publish user-contributed content, such as questions. [Their stated goal](http://stackexchange.com/) is to "build libraries of high-quality questions and answers". SE leaves the determination of what is a high-quality question to the members of each SE community. The members may reasonably decide that, e.g., "Find the inverse Laplace transform of $(3s+4)/(s^2-9)$" is not a high-quality question, and should not be included in the library. This is why they are given closing&deletion tools by SE.

Comment: @user75064, there are many academic questions that teaching faculty can, with impunity, decline to answer. The question was about what would happen to untenured faculty who systematically phrase those refusals in the prevailing MSE style.  The SE point is an interesting one that I will comment on later.

Comment: @user75064, the obligations of SE are pretty much nonexistent for this discussion.  They offer a free private web service and can do whatever they want, including defining all unclosed questions as "high quality archived content" and all closed questions as "low quality deletable junk", whatever implications that has.  The users can also do whatever the software allows.  SE has designed the site to try to align the result of users' actions with SE's goals, and it is a *very* interesting political phenomenon that many users confuse the two, citing SE statements as controlling what we should do.

Comment: The inverse Laplace example is a good one.  If "find inverse Laplace of [quite specific function]" is an overly localized, low quality question, how can it be that the even more localized "what is the error in my calculation of [the exact same Laplace transform]" is a high quality question, worthy of archiving because of its value for future readers who will flock to SE via Google?  Wouldn't the more general problem, involving the transform alone, and without any cruft like "thanks in advance" or "here is [stuck or wrong attempt] that I tried" be the one of higher quality?  @user75064

Comment: (continued) ... The more verbose, effort-displaying version of the Laplace transform question would definitely be higher quality on a *tutoring site*.  But that is not something that Stackexchange is designed to do, and if the goal is a library of high quality question, I don't see how a switch from a straightforward question-answer model (is question well defined and mathematical? is it interesting on those terms alone?) to a pseudotutorial will do anything except cause contradictions between the design and the utilization, and this leads to all kinds of problems down the road.   @user75064

Comment: @zyx I'm glad you found something interesting in my comment. You make a good point: from the "archival value" viewpoint no kind of routine homework question can be defended, copy-paste or not. Yet, *some* such questions indirectly facilitate creation of higher quality content. They keep experts engaged on the site by giving them something to answer *now*, instead of waiting until a deep question in their area drops by. Most mathematicians are used to alternating between research and teaching tasks, and having a similar balance on Math.SE may boost their contributions of both kinds.

Comment: (continued) Answering a Math.SE question posed by a student in their own words comes naturally to me, since it resembles what I do on daily basis anyway. Solving a problem where no student-generated text is present does not feel the same. It feels more like finding a problem written on a piece of paper slid under my office door, with no name or explanation. In such a situation, it is not my natural reaction to write down the solution and slide the paper back into hallway. More likely, I'll be inclined to throw it into a recycling bin. The SE equivalent of the latter is deletion. (@zyx)

Comment: @user75064: It does feel the same to me: specifically, it feels like the student who walks into my office, shows me a problem, and says ‘I’m lost; I don’t get this at all’. In some cases it turns out that the OP here is actually in better shape than that student, but that’s still what it initially feels like to me.

Comment: @user75064, there is a very exact SE equivalent, *ignoring unwanted tags* (does that sound familiar?). In the story you have a predefined category of "slipped under door" that you know you do not want to interact with.  Or, if you sometimes do read those under the door questions before deciding what to do, the exact analogy is reading a question and *doing nothing* (or answering, should you choose to).  Throwing a question into your office trash leaves the author of the question free to slide it under other doors, and people behind other doors are still free to answer it.  Deletion does not.

Comment: @Tristen I can't agree with this more. I only ever post a question when I'm completely lost. I think posting questions is actually quite time consuming (whether or not it really is, it sure feels like it) -- there's the typing up of the question, then waiting for posts, then reading through multiple answers. I always try not to post a question just for that fact. And I usually post only when I'm completely lost. It can be frustrating when all you get is doubt. I think some of the people with high rep points can forget that math is more difficult for other people. This is just IM*H*O.

Comment: Whenever I'm new to any site I do a whole ton of reading before I do very much writing at all. Every site is a community, like a bunch of friends. There are inside jokes, ways of talking, etc. The best way to get involved is to watch and listen, then contribute when you know you have something new and valuable to contribute. On a site like this that means a lot of searching to see if someone has already asked an equivalent question or given a better answer. It's not just Math.SE that can seem cold to newcomers. Most forums I read are like that.

Comment: While you do make a good point about not every homework problem bringer being here to have someone do their homework for them, I think that if you stick with MSE long enough to vote on closing questions, you will run into a lot of "do my homework for me" questions.

Answer (score 31):

> Some people do make an effort, just saying.

This -- along with some means of actually making this visible in one's question -- is all people have been asking for. We (meaning the "bitter" people) want people to ask questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379896/seeking-fourier-series-solution-on-laplace-equation-still-looking-am-i-on-tra), rather than like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377073/calculate-the-fourier-transform-of-bx-1-x2a2).

The bitterness you refer to is that there has been a recent upheaval where it was realized that there's enough support for the opinion that we've allowed far too much junk on MSE to break the long-standing deadlock versus the opinion we want everything on MSE, and that didn't go pleasantly.

And so we're still in a transition period in the wake of that argument. I expect things to settle down as people get more acclimated to the change and can devote more effort towards working out the nuances of which questions require action and what that action should be.

Comment: Students can get stuck and have no idea how to proceed. For those who have been doing this a while, the idea of using a contour integral to find a Fourier Transform is almost second nature. However, for those just starting out, a gentle hint is all that is needed to answer the second question. Once they have tried the contour integral, they might amend their question with more specific difficulties.

Comment: That's quite a self-serving summary of the "recent upheaval", but even if correct, the fact of a transition period (which I agree is taking place, at least on some matters) would suggest allowing the transition to take effect on its own and not posting threads whose apparent intent is to manipulate moderator elections.

Comment: @zyx: "threads whose apparent intent is to manipulate moderator elections"... what are you smoking and where can I get some?

Comment: @Willie: I’m not convinced that [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9330/should-problem-statement-questions-be-an-issue-for-the-election) was posted with conscious intent to manipulate the moderator elections, but it is certainly open to that interpretation and could have that effect whether intentionally so or not.

Comment: How is discussing whether something ought to be a topic for an election "manipulating" that election? Manipulation has a distinct negative connotation here (as in, involving methods that either due to legal or ethical reasons ought not be used).

Comment: @Tobias: If you read the comments over there, you know the answer to your question. If you didn’t, your question is premature. (Whether you agree with those comments is a separate issue.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have been reading the comments. And I don't disagree that the thread seems like an attempt to influence the election. But to me, using the word manipulation carries an implication of wrongdoing to some extend.

Comment: @Tobias: I think that zyx intended the negative implication, and I think that it’s defensible, though — as I said in my comment — I’m not convinced that it’s correct.

Comment: (Are we getting derailed here?) TBH, I'm not even sure exactly what I'm supposed to be accused of, and haven't been particularly inclined to humor zyx and prompt for clarification. The (intended) extent of my "manipulations" was to throw out the idea of separating the moderator election from the PSQ topic(s), after having developed a concern that being a recent hot-button topic might cause it to influence the elections more than it actually deserves, and am surprised at the apparent negative reaction (unrelated (?) to zyx's accusations) to what I actually stated along those lines.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I thought zyx was referring to this post here. If that's what he/she intended, it would've been clearer had he/she linked to the thread being referred to.

Comment: @WillieWong, I spoke of "posting threads" which in SE parlance means addition of new questions to the meta.  So it seemed clear enough that it refers to something beyond this answer (which is also troubled, as it pre-empts large swaths of the discussions on meta by smugly declaring everything to have been settled, with only a few minor details left to be arranged).  If you no longer stand behind your first inflammatory comment, you have the power to edit or delete it. It doesn't matter all that much how the comment votes go, but trolling for "this guy is crazy" upvotes doesn't help anything.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I thought of explaining the remark with an answer in the other thread, but lacked the time and inclination.  If this comment discussion is an indication of interest I might do it.  The present answer is worse in some ways, and probably more worthy of comment, but is not out of line with the way site works.

Answer (score 19):

I browsed the list of [new users](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) and took a look at how they were received. Most did not post anything yet, but almost all  of those who did received non-negative scores, and more often than not, answers. Even some less-than-stellar questions such as [Find Laplace Transform of the function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381697/75064) were answered. One question was downvoted and then upvoted twice: [How can a matrix be Hermitian, unitary, and diagonal all at once](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381702/75064)

On the first two pages of "New Users" list I found just one user whose question was downvoted and closed (link removed, since the question was reopened).

Overall, I think  the treatment of new users is not as rough as it appears from your post. (I admit that I have no data regarding unregistered users, who do not appear in the list.)

---

> MSE should be as much about camaraderie as about solving particular problems. I have seen many of my own friendships grow with peers as we explore some particular problem together. I would suggest that perhaps as a community, more "communing" could be done.

Here I disagree. First of all, SE is not a social network. Even so, there is quite a bit of socializing going on in the main chat room, and it seems that a number of frequent users maintain contact via non-SE tools (facebook, email, skype, etc). Given that the channels for networking are so plentiful,  it should be easy for us to stick to math on the main site.

Comment: The rest of your points are fine, but I disagree about the last paragraph. Math.SE is very much about social networking. At least for me (I don't have a facebook account and don't plan to get one).

Comment: The community sense should extend from the common bond of interest in mathematics.

Comment: I agree with your last comment. However, I actually disagree with your assessment of how new users are treated. Specifically, with regards to the question you cite which was downvoted and closed. Currently, the time stamps are: Question posed (10 hours ago). OP asked what they have tried (10 hours ago). OP provides satisfactory response (10 hours ago). This means, roughly, that within the hour the OP was showing a willingness to engage. And yet the question is closed! It does not make MSE seem friendly...(looking at the edits - moderator intervention? Seriously?!?)

Comment: My point is, the default does seem to be "close". Even if this isn't the majority default, the fact is that it happens enough for new users (for example, Tristen, the OP here) to notice means we have a problem.

Comment: @user1729  Tristen's observations apparently  come "from the comments to most of the posts I have seen over the last couple of days on meta". The second comment under the question also states that. Sure, reading meta debates is not something I would recommend to new users. (Eric Naslund said something of the sort in his resignation post).

Comment: @user75064 Ah, forgot about that part of his post. However, as I said in my comment to the question, whenever I suggest to my students that they ask questions here they do not want to.

Comment: @user1729 I wonder if your students' reluctance has to do with Math.se specifically or online fora in general. Are they comfortable with asking at Yahoo Answers or Art of Problem Solving?

Comment: @user75064 Just MSE. (And it isn't just a small subset of a single year group, and nor are they studying basic calculus.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Like editing Wikipedia, contributing to an SE site is a *social activity*. But SE is certainly not designed with *social networking* in mind; there is no way to send a message to another user, for example. So, if the OP finds the site not very social, it may be [by design](http://math.stackexchange.com/about) "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." Of course I do not advocate going from "not very social" to "anti-social".

Comment: I think sometimes there is quite a bit of chit-chat going on. I don't usually visit our chatroom (which is designed for that) because my time zone is what it is. But in the comments many jokes and anecdotes are shared, mutual cheering for each other takes place, professional courtesies are exchanged and such. Some would like the site to be all business, but we also like to add some levity given half a chance. Granted, the platform is not ideal for that, but it is good enough.

Comment: But conceding the point about the difference between social activity and social networking.

Answer (score 19):

Keep it short, this question [Vector field on an odd sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370886/vector-field-on-an-odd-sphere)   by this user https://math.stackexchange.com/users/52042/b11

He "pinged" me six times to answer his question. I had already given everything necessary in my first comment. After I said I had done enough, he serially downvoted me and Zev. This person sees MSE as an alternative to ever reading his book or working.

I think Asaf would know how to make up a list of probable students asking way too many questions.

The worry here seems to be about new users. Fine. With no visible track record, it would help to know the book and what material is in the chapter immediately preceding the question asked. This would tell me that the person asking has actually read the material immediately preceding the question.

Here is another winner, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12796/victor Little interaction with me, I got weary early.

Comment: I sympathize: repeated pings of this kind are extremely obnoxious, apart from any integrity issues. There should be a way to walk away from a thread and never hear from it again. Hypothetically speaking: if you deleted your comment under the question, would the OP be able to ping you again? I could not find an answer in [meta.SO thread on @replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019).  I know it's impossible to ping a user who never participated in the thread; I don't know what happens if the user participated but then removed their input from the thread.

Comment: @user75064, I left it there. I won't say the pings failed to piss me off, but I did not have much trouble deciding what to do, which was to say that I had done enough. Years ago, I would regularly get caught giving some answer, then the OP (on MO or here) would say You haven't done enough, write more, and I would. Lately, not as much.

Comment: I’m afraid that my reaction is *So what?* There are obnoxious people everywhere, and B11 is most unrepresentative of my experience. And I’ve little sympathy with complaints about Victor: he accepts answers, and he’s answered $13$ questions himself, with six acceptances.

Comment: Asaf doesn't know SQL (and has very little motivation to learn that too), so he is limited to the available data.SE queries, with the occasional minor modification.

Comment: @Brian, I was aware that you and I disagree on most MSE issues, certainly after your comments on Qiaochu's verbatim homework Meta proposals. I don't expect to convince many people of my viewpoint, but I do like to say it now and then. You hold the majority view, including the continuing moderators. Want to be moderator? It would involve less friction for you than for many others.

Comment: I have had a lot of multiple-ping experiences (these are called *help vampires* on MSO) but this has been more the case with the eager, show-maximum-effort posters who are being held up as the model of good question etiquette.  I am coming more and more to two ideas from experience on the site: -- not answering questions where there is any ambiguity about what is a complete answer --- and viewing "shown work" as a negative unless the OP wants the work analyzed (so if somebody does post their efforts, it is as logical as WHYT to ask, "do you want that examined or is it decoration?").

Comment: @zyx, what is MSO? oh, and what is WHYT, perhaps what have you tried? I don't see any zyx on MO, do you use a different name?

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vampires ) and, yes, What Have You Tried.

Comment: Will, I am a frequent MO user but under a different name.  Maybe the two profiles will get combined when MO changes to SE 2.0, maybe not. Since these sites are different religions, in some sense, I separate the identities.

Comment: I think we can save ourselves a lot of heartburn by simply recognizing why we are here on M.SE: because we enjoy math and people who enjoy math.  I answer certain questions here because I love to solve the problems posed in those questions, and I love to interact with others on this site.  As soon as it is no longer fun, I am done.  I do not have a set limit, but when someone makes it clear that they are here because they do not like math, I will note their name and disappear.

Comment: Now, that same user has starting pinging people in *other* completely unrelated questions for help: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/382465/19440

Comment: @mrf, there is also a Chat feature for MSE. This has, probably against system design, remained a single room where people drop in and later drop out. There are plenty of newcomers who put a question on Main and then bug people on Chat about it forever.

Comment: @Ron: I sympathize, but I don’t myself actually mind helping those who don’t like mathematics if they’re willing to work at it. Some folks may remember a beginning calculus student whose name began with *J* who complained bitterly (and somewhat unreasonably) about the unreasonable expectations of his instructor and the author of his textbook but who posted a lot of questions and did actually persevere, if not always to very good effect; I can work with someone like that, though I could have done with less moaning.

Comment: I lectured a course for non-honours students this year. They all hated maths, all claimed they were rubbish at it, and they are all going on to be maths teachers (which doesn't bode well for the future of humanity!). On the other hand, those who turned up were all willing to put in the effort. Most enjoyable course I've taught!

Comment: @user1729, "They all hated maths, all claimed they were rubbish at it, and they are all going on to be maths teachers" - I now wonder how many "teachers" past and present were actually that way. \*shudders\* If you did manage to get through 'em, then good on you!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I think we are on the same page.  I was complaining about the posters who do not want to work, but just want everything done for them.  I totally enjoy working with people who are having a rough time grasping this or that concept, but are clearly giving it a go.

Answer (score 13):

I am sorry that you have not been feeling welcome here. I hope that this feeling will go away when you see how much "good" is actually going on here. And I hope that we might convince you that your feelings are mostly a misunderstanding.

You write:

> ...from the comments to most of the posts I have seen over the last couple of days on meta, **nobody** really wants to see anything from anyone new on MSE

Remember that we are all people here and we make mistakes. Some times our mistake is that we speak/write before we think. However, I don't see how comments given recently could give you the impression that we don't want to see *anything from anyone new*.

So let me be *somebody* who is now telling you that I want to see something from, in particular, new people.

> There seems to be alot of bitterness, especially regarding the homework problems situation.

That is true, and again, the words spoken aren't always the best. As mentioned, we don't have anything against "new people", but it can be a bit frustrating when you see a question that just commands "do my homework". For me personally, there is an ethical problem here. As a teacher, I take cheating very serious, and I wouldn't not want my students seeking out someone else to actually do there homework. It is fine helping people with homework questions. In my opinion a student doesn't learn much from just being given a solution. Learning happens when the student has to think for him/herself. And it is hard for me to be a part of something if I have a feeling that it is ethical. If the word on the street is that "*Over on Math.SE they just give the answer away, and I don't have to do anything. It is great, I don't even have to do my own homework anymore*", then do I really want my name associated with that?

> While I understand that many people may be looking for a handout it is unfair to assume that is the case for anybody asking a homework question, or help understanding or clarifying some aspect of a particular area. Some people do make an effort, just saying.

Yes! Lots of people do make an effort. I see plenty of good homework questions and I see a lot of good answers. *No one* (that I know of) is saying that all homework questions are bad in and of themselves. The problem is the question that shows absolutely no effort.

If I am to try and help you, then the best thing you can do is to tell me what the issue is. If you have a (homework) problem that you can't do, then tell me what it is about the problem that is causing trouble. If you have absolutely no thoughts about the problem, you could tell me what class the problem is from. Where did you come across the problem, and so on. Those questions, I would say, you should always be able to answer. And writing just a bit about where the problem comes from and a bit about your background ... well that is effort in my mind. I don't know your background. If you have never heard about the product rule, then it might not be that helpful for me just to show how you solve the problem using the product rule. I might want to tell you about the product rule.

Oh, and no offence taken :)

Comment: It has been a great pleasure to see how this discussion has played out.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of "What have you tried?" perhaps we should write "If you show us what you have tried perhaps we can figure out how that can be the start of a solution." Oral statements have an associated tone of speech. Written statements lose the tone. A statement of some sort needs to indicate the tone.

Comment: The words "quality standards" have a similar effect.  To see how current practices are working, the daily closed list has examples like this ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391115/convergence-tests ) and this ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385739/graduate-linear ) .   There is un-necessary antagonism and drama that can be avoided by silent methods like downvote, close vote, do nothing (and let others decide if they want to answer), add filterable tag.

Comment: @zyx I do not see how a downvote is helpful in such situations.