# Is deleting a question while it is still on hold too quick?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This is a follow-up (**not** a duplicate) to an old question on Meta:

[Are we too trigger-happy about deleting (relatively) new posts?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16725/9464)

I have noticed recently that there are lots of on-hold questions being deleted. Here is an incomplete list:

- [Deleted] [How can we decompose $A=2x^2+2y^2+5xy+5x+7y+3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657605)
- [Deleted] [Proving bijectivity by finding “the inverse”.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2616329)
- [Deleted] [Math inequality …please help](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657533)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [How many ways are there to place 16 identical balls in 4 distinguishable urns such that each urn contains at least 2 balls?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2658161)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Probability of one of five events occurring](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2658153)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [How many functions $f: \{1,2,\ldots , n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ satisfy $f(x+1)-f(x) \in \{0,1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2658150)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Prove that algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$-algebra if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2655631)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Boundedness of given parametric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2653845)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Symbolic estimation of the Logarithm function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2652857)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Summation of series, further maths A level](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657684)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Using $y$ instead of $x$ in an equation for solving area between two curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657963)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Is the Feigenbaum bifurcation parameter 1.4081?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2658394)
- [<s>One deleted vote</s> Deleted] [Floor function of $\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657760)

Such deletion could be rather quick if it were coordinated by folks in the CRUDE room. IMHO, deleting an on-hold question makes the notice such as "Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking." rather useless.

> **Question**: Is deleting a question while it is still on hold too quick?

Comment: A couple of those questions were on hold for less than 24 hours before they were deleted. That's certainly too quick.

Comment: I had the same feeling and post [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20871/99914) sometimes ago. But I definitely do not know how long should we wait before deletion.

Comment: As a side remark, the first three questions had been previously deleted by the same trio of users. None of them cared to post even a comment here. But two of the questions have been reopened since, and just as promptly they now each have $1$ delete vote again, and all posted answers have been downvoted in block. I call that bullyish behavior and poor communication on someone's part.

Comment: @dxiv Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment is a sure way to make ineffective the whole mechanism, simply because of the mass of junk that (at least some users think) should be eliminated. Simply put, the site was not meant to function like this and it would quickly succomb to the weight of dead wood if this request was implemented. Note that this exact suggestion has been made and discussed (and refused) several times before.

Comment: @dxiv As a concrete case, take the first question the OP is linking to above (2657605). Personally, I am **grateful** to the 8 different users (five to vote to close, three to delete) who took on their time to study the question, decided it was not following the modus operandi of the site (a rather clearcut case) and acted **as is explicitely recommended in such circumstances**. Declaring that simply following "the law" is *bullying*, seriously?

Comment: @dxiv closing and deleting terrible questions is a service to the community and people have absolutely no obligation to explain.

Comment: What does the downvote to this post mean? Should I simply understand it as a strong NO to the question in the title? Then would you give your comment/answer explaining why you think so?

Comment: @Did: "Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment" I don't think that's what dxiv means. This post is specifically discussing whether deleting an `on hold` question *before* it is `closed` is too quick. Your comments are mainly about whether we should delete the so called "junk" or not.

Comment: Not quick enough, @Jack, when you've been proven to intervene and change questions to something entirely different, to organize reopen campaigns, upvote posts out of pity, for some ill-conceived notion of justice?  Can I ask you if you might be too trigger happy to manipulate asker's closed posts, to create different questions than were asked, edit and edit and edit and prevent anyone trying to help the asker retain the question they in fact asked?

Comment: @amWhy: your comment is off-topic and rather rude. And it seems to me that you don't want to give a reason at all why you think it is not quick but simply want to demean me, personally. What is your point?

Comment: ...  You could have easily come up with a list thirty  times the size of your list of questions. that were  deleted after they were closed, to show that most closed questions are not deleted too prematurely.  When you are ready to stop acting divisively, to discuss reality, without mis-characterizing the work of many users, perhaps we'll all be happier.

Comment: Jack, don't blame or attack me or any other user personally, instead of addressing the substance, the Point.  You never answered what your point is, did you?

Comment: Just like you have always done, Jack.  You merely dismiss arguments, and avoid taking responsibility for your misdeeds, as well.  This isn't about "bad users who at times delete."  It's also about bad questions, and bad answerers, and bad editors.  The  "boogey man" doesn't reside in CRUDE, where you yourself spent quite a bit of time in a zealous quest to delete a few users' posts.  But since you want to point fingers, and avoid justifying your hyperbole's and missteps, as well, no discussion can take place.

Comment: @amWhy: It seems to me that you constantly want to put off-topic comments by demeaning and distorting me and **not** want to answer my question in a reasonable way, I will not reply to you. If you do have a good reason for quickly deleting on-hold questions, **PLEASE write your own answer** and I'm listening. If you simply want to question my motive of posting this question, and think if there is any conspiracy against you, I suggest you stop.

Comment: Then stop implying there is some sort of conspiracy of dedicated users who seek no gain for their work, to downvote and/or delete just out of malice.  Don't ask from others the respect you refuse to give them.

Comment: What do you mean by "too quickly"?  (You are asking if  deleting a question while it is on-hold is deleting it "too quickly").  Most questions of questionable quality (-2-2 range, say), cannot be deleted while "on hold".  If there are questions that garner a significant *net* vote total that is $\leq 3$, then clearly, the community has weighed in on the quality of the question.  At times, such a question may be deleted while still on hold.  But it seems like you are suggesting, Jack, that no matter how low the vote, (say -12?) a question should not be deleted while on hold.

Comment: This would also include questions with obscenities,  hate language, downright rude, and spam, despite $\geq 10$ downvotes, it would be too soon to delete if it is still on hold?  What about a question says: "You must find the derivative of $f(x) = x^2$ for, ASOP, and you MUST include all the steps.  I don't want any hints. Just give me the steps and the answer. HURRY!"  Oops, well, yeah, likely high downvote count.  But alas, you are suggesting that moving to delete such a non-question is too premature so long as the question is still "on-hold"?

Comment: Would you please either bring your long comments to a chat room or write your own answer? You seem to have a **good** reason to believe that on-hold questions should be deleted quickly. Do you want to talk to everybody or just me?

Comment: In my last two comments, I am sincerely asking if or when we should consider a post for deletion, even if on hold.  These are honest questions. They are not comments to you alone.  They are scenarios worth considering by all.  I'm suggesting that the status of on/hold vs. closed isn't as clear-cut as some would think, at least in some cases.

Comment: @Jack ""Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment" I don't think that's what dxiv means." Sorry but I am no mindreader hence I can only judge the OP's intent from what they write. In the present case, what they write clearly points to the "requir(ement) that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment" -- which, as I explained, is a terrible (although somewhat natural, I guess, seeing how regularly it is formulated) idea. Would you be trying to obscure the debate?

Comment: I am not a mindreader either and I was simply saying that I don't agree with your interpretation. I have said in a previous comment that your first two comments are mainly about whether we should delete the so called "junk" or not, which is *not* about what I'm asking in this post. I don't think such clarification is obscuring the debate.

Comment: Answer: no, it's not too quick in most cases to delete a post prior to the sacred 5 day transition from on-hold to "closed".  Waiting too long to delete many questions (on hold and no longer of interest to the asker because their homework or take-home-test deadline has passed) is just as bad at times, as deleting another earnest question, showing effort, too soon.   Don't look for a magic period of time to define a "open for deletion"...  and certainly don't let anyone to mandate that everyone else abide by their own agenda to make everything non-deletable for at least 5 days.

Comment: @Did `Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment` You must be replying to something other than my comment above. `Declaring that simply following "the law" is bullying, seriously?` As you are certainly aware, [the law](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says that the regular grace period before deletion is 2 days, scaled up "*to the number of votes on the question and all its answers*", with an exemption being made for "trusted users" when the score goes -3 or lower.

Comment: @Did IMHO downvoting both the question and all posted answers in block as to bring the score low enough to take advantage of the exemption is *not* what the law had in mind. Coordinating all those downvotes between just a few "trusted users" in CRUDE makes it even shadier. Lastly, re-voting to delete immediately after the question had been just reopened as having been deleted too soon the first time around is, yes, bullyish in my books.

Comment: @ZacharySelk `closing and deleting terrible questions is a service to the community` What fraction of the community even had a chance to weigh in, if the question was deleted within hours? A few users rushing the decision, and claiming to do it in the name of the entire community - that's precisely the point of contention here.

Comment: @dxiv People are free to undelete if they see fit

Comment: @ZacharySelk `People are free to undelete` Only those with 10K+ rep, which is less than $\,0.2 \%\,$ of the MSE total [at last count](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/alltime/math). Hardly `the entire community` that my comment was referring to.

Comment: If the asker is really serious about the question, (s)he will respond to the feedback given via downvote/close vote and final deletion. It may well be the case that the asker is not addicted to MSE and the question gets deleted before (s)he has any chance to improve the question. No worry, just ask another question with improved version. Apart from the well intentioned people arguing here, the asker has the primary responsibility to fight for his cause.

Comment: @dxiv: Only those with 10k rep can vote to delete. And **as I stated in my answer** there is a barrier to deletion that is not there for undeletion. Why don't you ask all the 10k rep users why they **do not see fit** to undelete useless questions?

Comment: @user21820 `Only those with 10k rep can vote to delete` Yes, but the other $99.8\%$ "*lowly*" users should still have the chance to at least see the question before it's forever hidden from them. As much as some of the previous comments tend to obfuscate the point of the original question, that's not about why *deleting*, but rather why *rush* to delete. If the reasoning is "*let's get it over with, before too many have a chance to weigh in on it and perhaps even upvote, which would then make deleting more difficult for us*" then, sorry, that's gaming the system IMHO.

Comment: @dxiv: I find it very distasteful when users who do not see the full picture rashly criticize other users. Any post that is closed (or on hold) can be deleted independently of upvotes, so upvotes **don't** make "deleting more difficult". You, like many others here, refuse to face the fact that you would not dump such lousy questions on your teaher's desk. Is this site a dumping ground now? If not, then why should you expect lousy questions to be given slack? Is it because you yourself have answered them?

Comment: Oh yes, that reminds me. The SE reputation system can be gamed, since anyone can answer a lot of PSQs by students to 'earn' reputation. I have actually seen with my own eyes a couple of users do just that (answering lots and lots of calculus PSQs) to reach 10k. Now who's gaming what?

Comment: @user21820 `Any post that is closed (or on hold) can be deleted independently of upvotes` Before making unfounded statements, I suggest you click the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) in one of my previous comments: ''*It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However,* ***the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.***". `why should you expect lousy questions to be given slack?` I don't expect that. I just don't see vigilantism as the right recourse.

Comment: @user21820 `Is it because you yourself have answered them?` That's not even funny, but I do appreciate that it stays more civil than someone else's name-calling in a recent comment elsewhere.

Comment: @dxiv: I was perfectly aware of that. My statement is not unfounded. Firstly I did not say the number of delete-votes needed is constant. Secondly, usually that criterion hardly has any effect. I think only in 0.1% of the cases I've seen so far did it 'make deletion more difficult', and we are certainly talking about the vast majority here. My remark about you answering PSQs (which is true) is because you insinuated that some users game the system in deletions. Please refrain from insinuations if you don't like the hard facts.

Comment: @user21820 `I was perfectly aware of that` But it didn't transpare from what you wrote, which is consistent with my other point from the first comment: "*poor commmunication*". `I think only in 0.1% of the cases I've seen so far did it 'make deletion more difficult'` Interesting number. If you cast 10,000 delete votes and only noticed 10 cases where previous upvotes had mattered, then all else aside, but I'd say you spend way too much time on delete-voting ;-)

Comment: @dxiv: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071) for how the number of delete-votes scales. More or less you need 20 upvotes to increase the number of needed delete-votes by 1. So what I said stands even if I didn't cast so many votes. No, I don't think I've cast 1000 delete-votes yet, but the "0.1%" was an order-of-magnitude estimate. We can't be so precise with everything, you know. (The link may be outdated, but the popularity part seems roughly correct from my experience.) And if 1000 users start helping with the cleaning up, I can stop delete-voting! =)

Comment: @dxiv "Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment // You must be replying to something other than my comment above." Must I? What is your purpose then when you write: "None of them [them = some users exercising the option granted to them by the mse system to vote to close the first three questions mentioned above] cared to post even a comment here"? In my book, this is called vilifying an action by raising an aggravating circumstance. If you mean otherwise, then you might want to explain/correct.

Comment: +1 ... here in Meta, that means "I agree with the OP"

Comment: It's nice to drop by meta every once in a while and read discussions that remind me why I participate less and less frequently here.  :(  $ \ $

Comment: @Did Whether and how downvotes should be owned up to is another question entirely. In this case, however, the emphasis was on "***here***". The first user who went right back to double-down on the dowvotes and delete-vote *could* have at least left a comment ***here*** why they chose to do so. They did not, but preferred to show off in defiance of the discussion and other users' reopen votes. That's a complete disregard of basic, common courtesy. Of course, none such is mandated by the MSE rules ad litteram, but you set the bar *very* low if that's enough justification for you to defend it.

Comment: I would be glad to know a partial list (at least of ten posts) which has been **undeleted** or **reopened** by the CRUDE users. No need to respond to me here (if at all) I also visit the CRUDE room sometimes and so you can respond there also (if at all).

Comment: @user170039: I have myself voted to undelete 39 posts and reopen 51 posts, including [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494843) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2389907). I will not waste my time giving more links. From memory, there have been users who come to the room asking for their question or answer to be undeleted (with reason) and we do help. People generally notice events that they don't like and hardly notice events that don't benefit them. If you see questions that should not be deleted or closed, **you** should post in the CRUDE room so that we can act on it.

Comment: Thanks for responding @user21820.

Comment: At least [partial response in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43020771#43020771) to @user170039's request.

Comment: Unfortunately I was a bit imprecise in my comment here (apologies for that). So let me try to rephrase it. I would be glad to know a partial list (at least of ten posts) which has been undeleted or reopened by the CRUDE users and also has been mentioned in the room. No need to respond to me here (if at all) I also visit the CRUDE room sometimes and so you can respond there also (if at all).

Comment: Note that the two links I mentioned above had been mentioned in CRUDE, so they satisfy user170039's updated request.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, so in the end, "Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment " was indeed relevant to **your** "comment above", not to somebody else's. Now that this point is cleared up, let me repeat once again: making dramas because some votes are not accompanied by a comment, as if one had just discovered a damning circumstance, is either naiveté or propaganda.

Comment: @Did `Ah, so in the end, "Requiring that every downvote and/or every vote to close should be accompanied by a comment "was indeed relevant to your "comment above", not to somebody else's.` My last comment was obviously posted in reply to your previous one addressed to me, and it does in fact *refute* your out-of-nowhere "*relevancy*" nonsense, the same one that you appear to be repeating now. I don't see how you could pretend to misread or twist what I've wrote before to something entirely opposite. Sorry, but I sometimes wish comments had a downvote button of their own.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry but what I wrote was the logical reading of your sentence "None of them cared to post even a comment here." If you meant something else and now want to disengage from this reading, you still can explain what it was you meant.

Comment: @Did [Sigh](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27918/is-deleting-a-question-while-it-is-still-on-hold-too-quick?noredirect=1#comment113744_27918).

Comment: Tangentially related: must we simply compare the deletion date to the off-hold date? Personally I'd rather compare it to the post date, because if the OP didn't improve their question from that time and multiple days have past, they are much more unlikely to look back. Perhaps then, though, the issue is that we aren't closing questions soon enough for the OP to care. I've checked a few of the questions and it may be the case for some of them. Posted, long wait to put off hold, and then quick deletion.

Comment: Adding onto the previous comment, getting put off-hold is merely a label. What if someone commented the question should've been improved and were ignored while the question was left open? Surely it is not reasonable to believe a question will not be salvaged when put off-hold if the OP will not listen to comments. In such scenario, is there really any benefit from waiting longer to delete? I'd think not unfortunately.

Comment: @user21820: It does but **partially**.

Comment: Maybe [this exchange in the CRUDE room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/conversation/chat-in-crude-room) is relevant to this post.

Comment: Perhaps this [transcript from the CRUDE room is relevant to this post.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2017/9/13).  Feel free to forward the the next day, or back up to earlier days, but it shows Jack a very active member of CRUDE.

Comment: @amWhy: The last message Jack posted in the CRUDE room (see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12692/jack?tab=recent) for details) was at Oct 1 '17 2:15 PM (i.e., 147 days earlier). It is not clear how "it shows Jack a **very** active member of CRUDE".

Comment: A [recent example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2676143/72031) shows that people who ask PSQs in general never bother to improve their question. The asker did return (after closure) and posted "thanks" to the answerer, but neither responded to comments for improving the question nor reacted to the closure. Once they get a satisfactory answer its over for them. Such behavior does encourage people (like me) to vote for deletion (without any coordination from CRUDE).

Comment: @Para, "a recent example shows ... in general" is a nonsense. You ought to know that you cannot show a general rule by exhibiting a single example.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes I know that rule and one must be extra careful in drawing conclusions empirically. But I don't think it is viable to put here a large list of such examples. The list given in the question already has some examples where asker does not respond. In some cases there is a response but no effort at improving the question.

Comment: @Jack I guess this message: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48040643#48040643 might apply to you too. Please let me know if you're interested in becoming an admin of the room.

Comment: @tilper you could alternatively get involved here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86992/welcome-to-mse and increase your participation.

Comment: @dxiv I guess this message: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48040643#48040643 might apply to you too. Please let me know if you're interested in becoming an admin of the room.

Answer (score 26):

There's a lot to process here, from the question (and the examples therein), the comments and the answers. I'll try to divide this answer in order to organize my thoughts.

First and foremost:

1. **Is deleting a question while it is still on hold too quick?**

This general question does not have a clear answer, mainly because people have different priorities. Risking being too reductionist, I think there are people that prioritize cleanness of the site, and there are people who prioritize a welcoming environment to the site. Both are valid points of view which should **not** conflict, but usually do for obvious reasons.

Talking about my point of view, I frequently oscillate between two thoughts:

1: Most things are non-salvageable, and thus it is a waste of time to try and attempt to heal everything.

2: I do not want to exclude people from a group simply because of lack of acquaintance with said group.

To be clear, this is in reality a false dichotomy. But in terms of large-scale behaviour, it is a good approximation, in the sense that if you want to significantly erase bad content you must allow yourself not to enter too personally in them (as reference, see discussions about downvote explanations: one of the arguments is that necessary comments would create a barrier for downvoting). But an answer must be given, so I will get to the second point.

2. **The examples.**

Personally, I think some of the examples were harshly treated. So, with respect to those examples: **yes**, I think the deletion was rather quick. I know that MSE's informal policies change with time, but [my very first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284564/the-k-th-difference-of-the-sequence-nk-is-constant-and-equal-to-k) would probably be on that list if it was made today (I think it is quite similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2655631/prove-that-algebra-mathcala-is-sigma-algebra-if-and-only-if) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658161/how-many-ways-are-there-to-place-16-identical-balls-in-4-distinguishable-urns-su) examples, and many others). If I could recall my train of thought in the time, my conception of mathematics was of a frigid and formal discipline. If my question was well-stated, clear and succint (and dry), it would be good. MSE helped me in part in understanding how context and communication is important to mathematics. Specifically, that single and simple $4$-word question from Did in the comments may have resulted in huge consequences. If he said something like: "We are not here to do your homework" like I've already seen people saying, I would probably refrain from asking anymore (curiously, it was not a homework). If my question was hastly put on hold and deleted, it would have probably been worse. This may happen more often than not, and this worries me a bit.

3. **In general.**

Being honest, there is a lot of garbage in this site. It is good that we have people who are willing to basically work for free for the maintenance of this site's well-being. In general, I personally think that there should not exist a 
time gap for deletion, and it is good to be this way.

But I think that it is worth mentioning that if you spend too much time on a job, your patience will eventually suffer from that. Seeing repetitive patterns will inevitably make you conflate things. It is natural instinct. For instance, you may see any question which does not provide what the person has tried as worthy of deletion. You will look at a question without LaTeX with disregard. It is good to bring this kind of discussion up so we can refresh our decision making. As is clear in the examples, there are a number of people who are quite engaged in the process of deletion/closure etc. I am grateful for their work, a work that I only occasionally do. My only concern is that if I, who do not partake in deletions so oftenly, have fallen for those "sins" of bias, I think it is not unreasonable to say that this may happen to those that do this recursively. The thing that I ask of them is only to listen with open ears the concerns of people who are not that engaged with deletion, and to consider things like those that I said in the previous "point".

I think it is also worth saying that I personally think that the deletions/closure etc as done today are **good** in general. This whole discussion is about improving them even further. We have a good site, with good community and with a good purpose. This leads me to my last point.

4. **An important observation.**

This is a little off-topic with respect to the question, but pertinent due to the comments etc.

I feel there is a lot of hostility sometimes in meta. I understand that for some of us, this website is a very significant part of their life and thus we hold it to heart, leading us to feel threatened or even attacked when our point of view regarding it is challenged somehow. However, I think that it is important to notice that:

*If someone comes to meta to discuss, they want the same thing as you: to improve the site. They are not your enemy, they are your ally.*

Different points of view should not change that.

Comment: Very well written answer. I hope everyone agrees to your important observation at the end.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Agreed with point 3 about doing too much, I need a break sometimes x.x

Comment: Very good points, IMO.

Comment: You managed to get a downvote on this excellent answer! Hard to believe that!

Comment: I guess this message: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48040643#48040643 might apply to you too. Please let me know if you're interested in becoming an admin of the room.

Answer (score 17):

I agree that questions that are put on hold should not be deleted too quickly.

Users might come back and improve their questions. This is not often, but I've seen occasionally users putting a lot more efforts into the question after it's put on hold. It could be that they do not find it necessary at first to put more effort, since they found their ideas going nowhere.

On the other hand, I do not see what is gained by deleting those questions quickly, instead of waiting for sometimes.

Personally I will, in general, wait at least for two days before voting to delete. I do not expect users to visit MSE and to be responsive continuously. Even for myself: I do have my phone connected to MSE at all time, but I am able to do some serious editing/voting only when I am in front of a computer. So waiting at least one day before voting to delete seem reasonable to me.

There are exceptions: I will delete immediately Spam, on going contest questions, and when the questioners clearly are not improving the questions (e.g. they wrote "I've found my errors, thanks" or "this site is not friendly, I am NOT coming back again!" or they showed in the comment there is no way they are able to even understand they are asking)

Comment: I appreciate you acknowledge there are circumstances in which you make exception of waiting two days to delete. That's important; and I'll add that when you list questions where the asker states in a comment  "this site is not friendly, I am NOT coming back again!" or when askers "showed in the comment there is no way they are able to even understand [what] they are asking" (brackets mine), you find enough reason to delete post haste, on hold, or not.  So I'm guessing you'd also acknowledge that, just as you see some (valid) exceptions as obvious...

Comment: ... the criteria admits of some subjectivity. E.g., It may be clear to you that an asker demonstrated they are not even able to understand what they asked, another user might object because that user believes the asker knows what is being asked, but having a hard time expressing it?  There is no getting around that there (1) are indeed valid exceptions, meaning that in some cases, it is best not to wait on deleting a question, and (2) whatever criteria is bound to be subjectively interpreted.

Comment: Also, questions that are "closed" (put on hold) remain on hold for five days.  So, you must recognize that being willing to cast a delete vote after two days, given no response from, or edit by, the asker, still amounts to casting a delete vote while a question is on hold.  Apparently, at the very bottom of [this Help Center question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), questions are considered "on-hold" for five days, not two, and there is absolutely no difference between the status of "on-hold", and "closed".

Comment: I think, one week is more realistic deadline.  One should take into account that not every user visits the site every day. To give additional message in comments what's going on would be also a good practice. During absence the posts should not be removed, maybe only  after much longer time. It would also a good thing  that the right to improve questions stay opened for anyone in the case of absence of the asker..

Comment: In any case, like you, I think waiting two days in most cases is waiting for a sufficiently long enough time before voting to delete a question.  There's nothing magic, nor any difference in status, between "on-hold" and "closed".

Comment: There is no such right, @Widawensen, beyond a couple of days, perhaps.  Are you saying that an answer that is wrong, and has been downvoted 25 times, should remain open, nonetheless, in case the answerer wants to come back in one year and edit it?  There is no right hold out indefinitely, even forever, and to expect this site to take up space and distraction, just in case, down the road, a user might come back and edit their post.  That is observe.  You need to remember that *asking*, as well as *answering* on this site are privileges, not automatically guaranteed....

Comment: Anyway, again, @Widawensen, I suggest you look into maintaining a blog, where you can insist on keeping every golden nugget, and every piece of popcorn, on *your* blog, as long as *you* want.  *That* is your right.

Comment: Downvoted 25 times is perhaps extreme case I didn't see such one, but 3 times probably can be improved. Maybe they would be useful additional classifying markers for example of type "Caution: homework" but there is no such feature I suppose. To make the process transparent can remove misunderstandings which can arise form the lack of information..

Comment: If this is worth taking into account, I will just remind the fact that a post goes into reopen review queue if it is edited [*within 5 days* of closure](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821). (I suppose this is well-known to users who are active in closing/reopening business.) Five days is also the period after which *on hold* is changed to *closed*, as explained here: [Two announcements: new “FAQ” and new “closure rules”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9956).

Comment: If this is worth taking into account, "I will just remind the fact that a post goes into reopen review queue if it is edited *within 5 days*" (of being put on hold),  after which the asker disappears and sees no point in fixing it (having already missed the deadline) and all this, despite some "wanna-be-do-gooder, on day five, steps in to "save" a, say, incoherent post by editing it themself, in order to at least ask something that might be coherent, even if it doesn't come close to representing the asked question, and for what end?  In such a case, the question would best have been deleted.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  [That post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9956) was posted in 2013.  Five years old, By definition, they are not new.  The site has changed significantly since 2013, and likely for the worse.

Comment: Final point being, @John Ma, your own "policy" is contrary to the proposal of the OP here.  Hooray!

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am aware of the different between on hold and closed questions,but it seems 5 days is an arbitrary set up. If there is any reason we should wait until longer, I am happy to know.

Comment: @Widawensen In general, if I receive an email and I did not reply for a week there are consequences: my advisor would give me a call to see if there is any personal issues bothering me, and my students will write in the evaluation that "the instructor almost never reply emails"

Comment: In any case, thanks for agreeing that waiting two days is sufficient, and that waiting five days is a bit of a stretch.  *So you are, in effect advocating that users need not wait five days before moving to delete a crappy post.*  For you, that may mean 2 days is good; for another, perhaps one day is sufficient.

Comment: @Widawensen  "To make the process transparent can remove misunderstandings which can arise form the lack of information."  We cannot force users to read, to learn, to listen to, nor follow  already existent material readily available for askers and answerers alike.  Don't put the responsibility each and every user has to to this site on the shoulder's of a handful of folks.  If askers don't bother to get to know the site and its expectations,  and answerers insist on answering crap, then they're not entitled to whine and and claim, "do-over!", and rant about some fictitious conspiracy!!,

Answer (score 12):

**[Nasse-setä](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasse-set%C3%A4)** [is very angry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy7I3NRgAeQ).

While I largely agree with the quality standards of C.R.U.D.E. activists, and won't really shed tears for the listed threads, the speed of deletion makes me uncomfortable:

- For the purposes of discouraging low-quality questions (and the rep-farming answers) the act of putting the question on hold is sufficient. This step should be done as swiftly as possible, and the use of chatroom resources to collect links to doubtful material is a great tool in facilitating this.
- Deletion, on the other hand, is a different animal. True, it is clear that many questions cannot be salvaged, and are best disposed of. I am not discussing such threads. But, I fail to see the need to delete potentially salvageable questions speedily. What's the rush? Giving a bona fide opportunity to fix a bad question feels like a decent thing to do. Because a newbie asker may be shell-shocked, they may require time to absorb what just happened. And even more time to digest the pieces of advice. They may have gone to bed already, planning to return a day later. 3 hours is not gonna be enough for such a user.
- But, I agree with user21820 in the cases, where the asker is a 3-year veteran of the site. Such an asker is IMO more likely just testing waters, trying to locate yet another rep-farmer willing to do their homework.

---

- I recommend a minimum of 24-hour grace window for askers to improve the question.
- But, if there's a reopen/close war, I wouldn't restart that 24 hour clock. IMO it should start ticking from the first closure.
- All this disagreement was foreseeable. If only we had decided not to allow homework questions to begin with. Sigh. We have made, IMO, a very good attempt to be accomodating. Almost succeeded, but without a **binding** (i.e. something e.g. we diamond mods would agree to enforce) code/policy for homework questions, the problem persists. If I only could turn back the clock :-(

Comment: I agree with almost everything you said - right up to the last point. Whether HW should be allowed *is* the disagreement.

Comment: Let me add that I do not approve of the practice of answering poor questions **before** the question has been improved. I want to emphasize the need for speed in the closing stage. The users indulging in answering such questions are IMO also responsible for this sorry state of affairs.

Comment: +1 for your answer and also for your last comment. I believe the contention over poor quality questions is not so much related to their deletion but rather due to the rep loss when the answers also get deleted. But I admit the desire to give answers sometimes is overwhelming and supersedes other considerations and I have fallen into this trap occasionally. One needs more self control here and perhaps the CRUDE room is just trying to help in this direction.

Comment: Very true @ParamanandSingh. Darn few saints here. Because: *When* **I** *do it, I am adding valuable content to the site, but when* **they** *do it, they are farming for rep*. The beam in your own eye and all that :-/

Comment: Jyrki, you can turn back the clock. Just not the flow of time. You may take comfort in knowing that (1) from a physical point of view, there is no difference and you can play this backwards, although that will also result in an increased accommodation of PSQ homework questions; and (2) you can be sure that if you turn back the clock, it would happen all the same. You think that the people who pushed so hard to be "maximally accommodating" are going to let someone who claims to be from the future change their minds?

Comment: ROTFL @Asaf. Thanks.

Comment: I fell from grace myself [just yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2680691/11619). Thankfully we have at least one user who cared enough to downvote my answer as a reminder.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is a reasonable downvote that you received. But this question is not about downvotes; it's about *deletion* - quick deletion, organized by a handful users who openly scold moderators and other users of all levels for simply answering questions. That is the behavior that I would hope that you as moderators could come to some agreement on. In the case of [RobJohns recent request for undeletion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/28017#28017), I don't think there should be any problem with the use of diamond powers.

Comment: @MarkMcClure You see, I'm in favor of scolding users who *simply answer questions*. From my point of view those users invited all the Calculus101 help vampires in, and ruined a fine math site while doing that. All so that they could gain a few ego points. I don't agree with rapid deletions, but in my opinion the bigger problem is that bad questions get answered so fast that the close voters have trouble keeping up with the pace. Personally I will happily give the C.R.U.D.E. gang some slack, if that is the only way to motivate them to continue putting bad questions on hold.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The reality is that, while some questions are clearly non-sense or spam, there's no real consensus on good and bad - even in the small group of moderators. PSQs, in particular, clearly fit the non-chatty Q&A format originally espoused by StackExchange. Like them or not, it's easy to see how a reasonable person could conclude that PSQs are fine. In fact, PSQs are probably why the vast majority of users (like them or not) are here.

Comment: Another issue with the CRUDE gang that they freely throw around denigrating terms, like "help vampire" and "rep whore". Where did those huge reputations come from in the first place? At least two of them have served long suspensions and at least one of those suspensions was for voting irregularities. For some of them (not necessarily all), their current actions are not consistent with their past.

Comment: @MarkMcClure How do you expect these users should react to somebody taking a dump on their lawn, which is what dumping homework amounts to? How would you react to that? Of course plenty of people will like homework problems because it fertilizes their egos (or displaces crap). Personally, PSQ is not a red flag for me. But a PSQ homework problem is. Neither askers nor the answerers pay any attention to site hygiene. If I have any say on the matter, this site won't be turned into a calculus honor roll. True, many of us think the site was better when we had 30 questions per day :-)

Comment: But, I'm quite tolerant of PSQs asked by laymen. Outsourcing homework here is the cancer I will fight tooth and nail.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess I expect them to react better than that. :)

Answer (score 11):

My feeling is that quick deletion, as organized by folks in the [CRUDE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) is a bit *too* quick. As a teacher of mathematics, I too am irritated that some folks get away with cheating here and I have participated in my fair share of deletions. Ultimately, I have to ask, though - does quick deletion do more harm or good?

According to [this Main Meta Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) which is linked from [this math.stackexchange help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions):

> for questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted. Basically, this includes most closed questions that cannot be improved and reopened.

Unless it's clearly an exact duplicate, I think it is rarely the case that a Problem Statement Questions (or PSQs, as some call them) cannot be improved.

Also, it's hardly the case that there is overwhelming community consensus on what to do with PSQs. While proposals nearly five years ago that PSQs [be banned](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/proposal-ban-verbatim-homework-questions-which-have-no-accompanying-text) or [at least discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement) received a lot of support, there was still a significant minority of folks who felt otherwise. Furthermore, those previous discussions don't really deal with deletion, but focus on down voting.

Furthermore, there *should* be dissent on this issue because PSQs have the advantage of being concise and mathematical. They are not chatty, open-ended, or subjective as the help center specifically advises users to avoid. Frankly, requests to an already confused user that they show work often makes the question more chatty and less clear.

One potential positive that arises from deletion is that it helps organize the site into a useful reference resource. While I do think this is a valid point, I also believe it's truth is greatly exaggerated. Frankly, vote count correlates rather poorly with post quality. I think it very unlikely that the quality of the enormous amount of information here will ever rival the quality of the well edited textbooks in a library.

Taking all this into account, my preference would be to see the pace of question deletion slowed.

Comment: You entirely mischaracterize the CRUDE chatroom.  Anyone, everyone is welcome there; there is no "organized" group to speak of.  Please don't characterize users who come to chat as covertly trying to organize anything.  You may claim your belief of the need to refrain from delete votes, despite your actual behavior to the contrary; I too am working on my own understanding of  the best interest of the site.  To suggest that some users who may disagree with you are therefore conspirators is over the top, and it's a straw-man argument.

Comment: Whenever you encounter a question that you think should not have been deleted, you have the privilege to vote to undelete it.  If a post is closed, and you think it should be reopened, vote to reopen it.

Comment: That whining users fail to make use of their option to vote to undelete, or to reopen is not the users who voted to delete or close problem.  If there was such an opposition to closing, deleting worth its weight, we'd see it en force, in more frequent undeletions and reopens.  That's your problem, if you fail to participate.  Don't blame some of the most active users on this site who aren't in it for the rep for your, and too many others', inaction.

Comment: @amWhy I fail to see how I've "whined" or mischaracterized the CRUDE chatroom. I'm well aware that it's been around for a long time and is *public*. I'm not at all under the impression that anyone there is acting covertly - nor did I say so. It's just simple observation that a small cohort of folks there frequent the chatroom and ping one another to draw attention to specific questions and to specific users. The effect is that the deletion process has recently been accelerated. In my opinion, as well as in the opinion of others, this has not been a good thing. My post simply articulates this.

Comment: And in my opinion, as well as in the opinion of many others, the posting of very poor questions and answers has accelerated, so in response, if you see an increase in deletions, perhaps consider that this is merely a consequence of the rapidly climbing number of poor questions, and very poor answers.  Deletions go up or down based on the influx of very poor questions.  Don't blame the messengers.

Comment: "My feeling is that quick deletion, as organized by folks in the CRUDE chatroom is a bit too quick."  I'm sorry you *feel* that way, but you are in error in suggesting that there aren't any organized folks in the CRUDE chatroom.  So your first statement is a misrepresentation of reality.

Comment: "I think it very unlikely that the quality of the enormous amount of information here will ever rival the quality of the well edited textbooks in a library."  Well that's only to be guaranteed by the continued influx of do-it-for-me PSQ's and rep-"hunters" who don't give a damn about site quality and will take a virtually empty post, and pretend there's a question, when there isn't, or they make it up for the sole reason of being able to answer it!.  So instead of condemning users who believe this site can be improved, if your not working to improve it, you're part of the problem.

Comment: "[...] rarely the case [...]cannot be improved" **As said** that misses the point in my opinion. For example the third question in OP certainly it could be improved. But what's the point. OP got an answer and that's that. Why waste time to bring it over the threshold of deletion. It won't be all that relevant regardless.

Comment: @quid Uhm... I think I agree. :)

Comment: Just a minor point about quality of content here. It's way more than what one gets from textbooks and classroom instructors. One reason is that most of those well edited books are not used as textbooks and another reason is that they are so few in number. Even famous books (like those yellow ones from Springer publisher) are genuinely dry/boring.

Comment: For the sake of showing two sides of the same coin, [I don't vote blindly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=40839407#40839407) in the CRUDE chatroom and I suspect the others don't either. I'll agree it has been a tad too fast sometimes, but there are times where I think it's too slow. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 8):

For some threads it is pretty clear from the get-go that there is no real use keeping and trying to improve them.

Sure one can turn every thread into something interesting, but for some it just seems like a poor allocation of resources.

Sometimes deletion is just fine, and everybody (including the original poster) can move on to more interesting things.

(I did not check all the examples. The above is a general statement.)

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, your question seems to be based on a false premise. Questions have to be first put on hold before they can be deleted. Secondly, questions that are on hold cannot be deleted quickly unless they have too negative score. I don't know the exact details of this, but this mechanism already prevents questions from being deleted unless the community downvotes them sufficiently. (This provides a barrier to deletion, and there is no corresponding barrier to undeletion.)

I consider it reasonable to wait **if** the asker is a new user. But take a look at your own examples:

[The first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657605/how-can-we-decompose-a-2x22y25xy5x7y3) was a zero-context question posted by a user that has been a member for nearly 3 years with over 1000 rep, who has consistently posted equally poor quality questions; see the most recent five: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348084), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2295398), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2260401), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2257679), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254670).

[The second question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616329/proving-bijectivity-by-finding-the-inverse) was also a zero-context question posted by a 3-year-old user, who certainly knows how to post good questions, so your implicit suggestion that the asker would not know the reason for deletion is moot in this case.

[The third question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2657533/1) was posted by a new user who did not put in any effort into the question despite the instructions that pop up right before every new user gets to post a question, telling them to use LaTeX and how to ask a good question. Observe that this user saw the close-banner and had plenty of time to improve the question, but did not, and the question was deleted 3 hours later.

---

Let me **emphasize strongly** that it is the **responsibility** of the asker to put **effort** into his/her own question. This site does not **owe** anyone anything; it is already giving free mathematical help to those who **wish to learn**. Someone here said (roughly) that a student ought to put in the same effort into a question that he/she would if the recipient was the teacher. If not, the student is just like treating Math SE as a dumping ground for questions that are too lousy to ask of the teacher. I think there have been many variants of this analogy, like [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9367/no-offense-intended-but#comment34067_9367) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26959).

See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for the 'official' site policy on how to ask a good question, which I believe is prominently shown to every new user on the Ask-A-Question page itself.

And, by the way, there is no way to maintain site quality if we leave junk lying around all the time. Eventually someone has to do the dirty cleanup work.

Comment: The third question – how much time did the user have, between the closure and the deletion, to improve the question? How do you know the user saw the close-banner?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: As I stated in my post, that user had 3 hours. He/she visited the site about 6 hours after the post was closed, did nothing for 3 hours, and then the post was deleted. Furthermore, I believe users get notified of deleted questions of theirs and can see them (including the banner even when it's deleted). In any case, you didn't admit that the first two cases are open-and-shut lousy questions that don't at all meet the 'official' site policy. Why don't you?

Comment: First, "Firstly, your question seems to be based on a false premise. Questions have to be first put on hold before they can be deleted" I don't think I have a premise in the post. (?) I'm posting what I have seen and asking for discussion. Second, this post is not about whether we should delete "PSQs" or not, but a discussion about whether deleting an `on hold` question before it is `closed` is too quick.

Comment: @Jack: I said "seems", because people who don't know the technical details may easily think (based on your post) that deletion is just a matter of delete votes. I myself would have thought that if I hadn't known what is stated in my first paragraph. However, if the question was not such a poor one, it would not get so many downvotes and hence cannot be easily deleted. If you aren't aware, many of those downvotes do not come from the delete-voters, but from users who don't even go to the CRUDE room.

Comment: I am curious, @user21820, how do you know the downvotes do not come from the delete voters? (On the other hand, users might not go to CRUDE, but they might read the transcript)

Comment: @JohnMa: I said "many ... do not come ..." Proof: There are often only 3 delete-voters, but a ton of downvotes. By the pigeonhole principle... Anyway, from my experience, many downvotes come from the close-voters, who are frequently different from the delete-voters. Just take a look at the last 4 questions in the list Jack gave in his question. I didn't even downvote any of them, so you can obtain a lower bound on the number of downvoters there must have been besides delete-voters...

Comment: @JohnMa  I do frequently downvote very very poor questions.  I also reserve votes each day to upvote good-well-asked-researched-investment-of-effort-from-the-asker.  I rarely, though have occasionally, downvoted an answer.  And I do delete when it is clear the asker him/herself has made no effort to improve a closed question, and also at times, when I believe that a allowing on "on-hold" question to remain to be more harmful than simply deleted quickly.  There is no correlation between down-voting and deleting, and certainly not between downvoting answers and deleting questions.

Comment: Three hours is plenty of time, 21820? Not in my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps, @GerryMyerson But certainly two days is plenty of time;  And do you admit of exceptions?  If someone posts nothing but "..........................------------ ++++++++++++", are we supposed to wait five days to delete it?  It's happened often enough (given some combination of strings that make no sense).  Okay, let's say not.  Are we supposed to wait five days to delete a post whose title says "See post", and in the post, there is only a link, from a drop box, for which users who dare to click on the link see incoherent scribbling?... let's say not....

Comment: @GerryMyerson While it is usually not the case that poor question need to be deleted within "3 hours", there are times (think profanity, hate speech, "is your refrigerator running?") where the only right thing to do is annihilate the post, asap, and there are other times when a question warrants a more expedited deletion;  To say "no matter what, thou shalt not delete any post whatsoevereth, until after five days hath passed, is absurd.

Comment: @amW, you are setting up straw men. My comment was clearly in the context of the discussion of one specific question, and it was not a question of the type you are describing. It was the third question listed in the original post here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Let me repeat myself that you have **not admitted** that **the first two cases are open-and-shut lousy questions that don't at all meet the 'official' site policy**. Until you do that, you are just arguing for the sake of arguing, rather than looking at the overall picture.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: that question was a PSQ and for quite sometime PSQ's are being treated harshly (thanks to some dedicated people in CRUDE). And for most PSQs, askers never give any response and this is not because of lack of time, but rather laziness.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh is your statement a general one or is it about that specific question that was closed within 3 hours?

Comment: @JohnMa: the third one in the list compiled in the current question and perhaps that was the one deleted in 3 hours after on hold. But the laziness remark is for most PSQ's

Comment: Yes I meant to say deleted instead of closed. Well I agree that most PSQs should be closed asap. I do not agree with the quick deletion though. If the asker did not have chance to react or read the closure reason, why can we tell them their question is not good? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @JohnMa: As I stated in my answer, that user had 3 hours. Contrary to Gerry, it's **obvious** that 3 hours is plenty of time. Suppose **you** were the asker, who is sincere about learning mathematics. Even if you make an initial mistake of posting a lousy question, when you visit the site you would see the banner, and then start reading its link to "**how to ask a good question**". And then you would realize you need to include some context. That should **not** take more than half an hour, unless in the first place you never spent any effort thinking about your question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Just to clarify, it wasn't deleted 3 hours after being put on hold. It was put on hold and then 6 hours later the user visited the site and did nothing for the next 3 hours, after which the question was deleted.

Comment: They see the close vote and do nothing for 3 hours: They could be working, transiting, studying or just sleeping in that 3 hours. I still don't understand, what is the utility of deleting the question quick? What is gained? @user21820

Comment: Repeat yourself all you want to, 21820, whatever the case may be with the other two questions, if the third question was deleted too quickly, then the third question was deleted too quickly, and that's something the community should be concerned about. To look at the overall picture, you and I would have to look at not just three questions but at every question that has ever been deleted – probably thousands of them – and debate how many of them were closed too quickly, and I doubt either of us wants to do that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You still refuse to admit the facts about the other questions in the list selected by Jack. Look, if Jack was only concerned with that one question (3rd in his list), he should have focused on it. No, he didn't; he gave the whole list as **evidence** that deletion has been too quick. I have **adequately shown** that practically the whole list is as **lousy evidence** as the questions in that list. The asker could easily have commented saying they would fix their question, and I would support leaving the question alone until they fixed it. No; the asker just didn't bother.

Comment: @Para, you assert that "for most PSQs, askers never give any response" and furhter that "this is not because of lack of time, but rather laziness," but you provide not a skerrick of evidence for these assertions. And even if what you assert is true, there is a serious fallacy in applying what is true of "most" people in any group to "all" the people in that group.

Comment: @JohnMa: Tell me, what is the utility of cleaning up dirt quickly? What is gained? Why not leave dirt lying around longer for everyone to see? Did you realize that is why some places are clean and some places are not? And see the other question by the same asker, which has been left alone and yet the asker still has done nothing to show any effort (obviously there has been practically no effort put in).

Comment: When I wrote, "Repeat yourself all you want to, 21820," I didn't mean that as encouragement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Then why are you responding? I think you want to have the last say, so you say "repeat yourself all you want" instead of saying "let me have the last say so don't say anymore". Hmm.....

Comment: I described that in my answer. Because, once in a while, the users come back with much more efforts into the questions. So there are utility to wait for sometimes: they might became good questions. Of course when it becomes clear that is not gonna happen, we will just clean that up.

Comment: And are you going to answer my question? Honestly I do not understand.....

Comment: @JohnMa: Which question? I thought I answered all your questions. Like I told Gerry: "The asker could easily have commented saying they would fix their question, and I would support leaving the question alone until they fixed it." and "And see the other question by the same asker, which has been left alone and yet the asker still has done nothing to show any effort (obviously there has been practically no effort put in).", and like I already stated clearly in my answer, "I consider it reasonable to wait if the asker is a new user." but why can't you accept that we differ on how long?

Comment: @JohnMa: Why do you think it is unfair if 3 delete-voters decide that it is time to delete a lousy question? Why is only your length of timing fair? And I think you know very well that Paramanand is correct that almost all PSQs are posted by lazy people. Askers have the primary responsibility for their own question. I don't see why anyone should disagree with that. This is not Math WorkExchange.

Comment: Your comment to Gerry is ..... weird. If you are busy/not available in that 3 hours, how are they supposed to write a comment on that? (And really, why could they think that is necessary, when you might come back later to edit anyway).

Comment: And I never said my timing is fair, if anyone disagree and convinced me I am open to it, just like what I tell Martin in the comment.

Comment: And sorry, I will have to sleep now, hope that this question is still here when I woke up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: you can visit the list of questions being discussed here and check if any asker has given any response. Mostly you will find no response. That is some evidence but yes most is not the same as all. And exceptions can be there, but those exceptional askers can ask again with more context.

Comment: @JohnMa: I see no reason why this Meta question will disappear. Your reason that they might think they can edit it later is possible in some cases, but as I told you they didn't bother to do it on their other lousy question, so the evidence is **not** in your favour. And askers who are sincere in learning will ask again. In case you aren't aware, they can **still see** their deleted post. I have not seen a single example of a sincere learner who gave up due to lousy question deletion. Show me one and I will change my mind! =)

Comment: @user21820 I am concerned about whether 3 hours between closure and deletion is sufficient for the users to react. Your above comment, correct me if I am wrong, implies that you deem that user are not coming back anyway. That's orthogonal to my objection. My objection is how 3 hours is considered plenty of time.

Comment: If you say the quick deletion is due to the fact that they are bad users and should not be given sufficient time. I may not agree, but I probably will not object.

Comment: @JohnMa: I think you disagree with me less than we thought. Let me make my last point clearer: I have not seen any **sincere learner of mathematics** get affected due to quick deletion of poor questions. If these users are the ones we value, then I see no difference whether a poor question is deleted quickly or slowly, and hence there should not be a **burden** on the users who care to clean up to have to wait and keep checking back on whether a poor question has been improved. It is ridiculous to expect us to put in more effort to track the question than the asker put into the question.

Comment: Perhaps, 21820, your definition of "sincere learner of mathematics" is anyone who doesn't get affected due to quick deletion of poor questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No. I challenge you to show me any user that **you** think is a sincere learner but got adversely affected by quick deletion.

Comment: Well, you've got it the wrong way around, 21820. If a newcomer was so bummed out by a quick deletion that she never came back to the site, how would either of us know whether or not she was a sincere learner of mathematics?

Comment: Let me show you two questions that I ask in my early days in MSE: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585483/maximally-connected-planar-graph) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540070/to-derive-an-inequality-of-the-form-fr-leq-cr-alpha). Can you judge from this two posts whether or not I am a serious learner? Are you sure you understand the real person sitting behind the computer, using just several posts?

Comment: @JohnMa: Just 30 min after you asked the first question, you posted one detailed comment (which I count as context) and also one more comment that you hardly know any terminology. I am lenient towards such users. Your second post was poorer, but tell me, would you really have gone away if it had been closed and deleted? Actually there is a hint in your second question that it was not asked with a bad attitude, because you wrote "can we show that ...?" instead of "show that ...".

Comment: @GerryMyerson: If you do not have evidence against my claim, why do you expect me to believe your counter-claim? We are getting nowhere with this particular line of discussion. Just accept that I will not accept your viewpoint without statistical evidence. I have seen thousands of PSQs but I cannot transfer my mental memory of my experience to you, so I can't use my experience to convince you, but don't expect me to just believe whatever you say either.

Comment: I made no claim, 21820, and I put forward no viewpoint. All I did was ask the question, how do you know who is a sincere learner of mathematics?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You made one explicit claim ("Three hours is plenty of time, 21820? Not in my opinion.") and many implicit claims, including that there are newcomers who are "so bummed out by a quick deletion that she never came back to the site" but is actually a "sincere learner of mathematics". If you don't believe there are such users, you should not be making that comment. If you do, the evidence I asked from you is still wanting. You also implied that we must look at **all** the deleted posts to get a good overall picture, which is obviously not true.

Comment: My point is that, your statement "I have not seen any sincere learner of mathematics get affected due to quick deletion of poor questions" cannot be proved or disproved by merely looking into several posts of a user.

Comment: 'You made one explicit claim ("Three hours is plenty of time, 21820? Not in my opinion.")' If you can't tell the difference between a claim and an expression of opinion, then I don't think we're going to get very far here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: If you can't tell the difference between "viewpoint" (your word) and "opinion", then I don't think you're going to get very far here. I assumed you used "claim" in the similar (English) sense, but that's still irrelevant to the fact that you are self-contradictory.

Comment: @JohnMa: Your statement "... cannot be proved or disproved by merely looking ..." also cannot be proved or disproved. Look, it's pointless to continue this discussion because neither you nor Gerry even show me a single user that **you think** (not prove) is a sincere learner but has been affected adversely by quick deletion. Until you do so, there's nothing more to discuss; we simply disagree and you have no counter-evidence.

Comment: I gave you myself as an example already right? You agreed that at least one of my question is poor right? I have provided an example where at least one (then) new user provided poor questions, but (I know) is a sincere learner. What else do you want me to show you? @user21820

Comment: And are you seriously using the word "can we" as a hint to see if a user is sincere?

Comment: @JohnMa: I consider **many factors**, unlike many other people. But if you want to continue, at least answer my question: Would you really have gone away if it had been closed and deleted?

Comment: Me? I won't. But I am asking a more fundamental question: before knowing if a sincere user will be scared away, I want to know how to identify sincere user: If you don't want to be too general, lets take that [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/532644/flower) in question: Is this person a sincere learner? @user21820

Comment: @JohnMa: I think you've misunderstood my point from the beginning. I never claimed that I could tell with 100% accuracy whether a user is sincere or not. All claim (and haven't seen a counter-example) is that sincere learners will **not** leave this site due to quick deletion of poor posts. And **if** my claim holds then I see no reason to criticize the way deletion is currently carried out. But to humour you, I'll explain in chat why that user is not sincere.