# Why was my answer to a meta question deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why was my answer to [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement) deleted by Moderator Alexander Gruber?
I believe it has no proper reason to be deleted.
Since it was deleted by a moderator, nobody except the moderators can vote to undelete it.

Comment: I agree that the answer shouldn't have been deleted. I voted it down, since I disagreed with it (and expressed so in my comments), but I think that deletion of meta answers should be reserved for answers that are deeply off-topic or are uncivil. (Also, it's not quite true that nobody except the original moderator can undelete it - any of the moderators could.)

Comment: @user61527 [*Also, it's not quite true that nobody except the original moderator can undelete it - any of the moderators could.*]
I edited the question.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, however: The moderator was the third to vote for deletion, so the deletion didn't rely on the voter being a moderator. It might just be a side effect that the answer is not subject to undeletion votes.

Comment: @user61527 [*It might just be a side effect that the answer is not subject to undeletion votes.*]
My point is that nobody except the moderators can vote to undelete it.

Comment: By now you must be accustomed to being treated unfairly. The unfortunate thing is that moderators, that one expects (perhaps unreasonably) to behave better than the rest of us, do not necessarily do so.

Comment: @AndréNicolas This is not a matter of whether a moderator should behave better than the rest of us.
I believe this is abuse of moderator power.

Comment: I join in asking the moderators to undelete.

Comment: @MakotoKato: My words were chosen with some care, and with the intent that they be wounding. I do not wish to worry about abstract questions about moderator power.

Comment: I "vote" to undelete the answer (even though I also disagree with the answer itself).

Comment: In case it's not really implied in my comment, I also "vote" to undelete the answer - that makes at least $3$ users who can cast undelete votes who would so vote.

Comment: I tried to vote that the post be undeleted. Was informed that it could not happen, that a moderator had voted for deletion. I suggest that the moderator agree, or resign.

Comment: The answer has since been undeleted by moderator mixedmath.

Comment: This comment thread is awfully inflammatory. Does nobody think of the obvious explanation that the side effect was a surprise?

Comment: @Hurkyl That's part of what I meant to convey in one of my first comments - the fact that a moderator did this is secondary to the fact that the deletion turns out to be binding. Regardless, I think that the moderators are quite aware that their votes are binding, which is why many of them refrain from voting on subjective manners until there are already $n - 1$ votes (and this has come up on meta before); so I really doubt that the result was surprising.

Comment: @user61527 There are two sorts of "binding", which your comment does not distinguish. A moderator's closevotes are binding in the sense that they take effect at once, but they can be reversed by non-moderators voting to reopen. Moderator's deletion votes cannot be reversed by non-moderators. The latter issue does not come up often, so it's possible the moderator did not consider this effect of the vote.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY You're right that the two issues are somewhat different. There are occasional meta discussions, though, about the binding deletions due to moderators - though most of these are in reference to the Community user's automatic deletion of posts. (But I would certainly *hope* that the elected moderators who have served for so long would be aware of the consequences of their votes).

Comment: @MakotoKato It pleases me to see that you stuck up for you response to that post even in the face of negative votes and requisite graying of content. If you had not done so, I would not have been able to read your opinion on the matter. Your opinion appears to go against the prevailing waters in that particular case, but it is honest, polite, and thoughtful. I see no danger in letting it stand as is; thoughtful polite opinions do not scare me personally even when they goes against my own sense of correctness.

Comment: Our friendly neighbourhood Mad Scientist has very recently made the following feature request on Meta SE: [Regular users should be able to undelete moderator-deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233466/214632).

Comment: @Hurkyl Even if that side-effect was a surprise, it does not answer the main (in my mind) question why the post was deleted at all. Admitting your interpretation, one should then perhaps ask all users involved. But the question does not go away by just saying it was perhaps a surprise it could not be undeleted, as this is not the main point IMO. (Though some comments revolved around it that is true.)

Comment: Answer deleted again...

Comment: As, while deleted, it is invisible to those below 10k, could you copy in your answer, and add the stated reason for deletion?

Comment: @Hurkyl: could you elaborate how the comment *thread* is inflammatory? With the exception of one comment by a user I've generally only seen polite and considerate, even OP sticks to discussing mechanics, not hypothesized reasons. As to the reasons hypothesized in that comment, I ended up here strolling through coming from a SO question in which I mentioned OP being subject to a childish vendetta here, so I'll add my voice to it (and make this arguably the second inflammatory comment). I haven't seen the answer and might bite my tongue if I ever do, obviously.

Comment: This is puzzling. If, as Hurkyl suggested, the comment thread was "awfully inflammatory" and the deletion was about the comments rather than the answer, why was the answer deleted *a second time* after all allegedly inflammatory comments had apparently been removed? Now this seems to me a cencoring of speech rather than a maintenance of public order. But I agree that this is not really a moderation issue, but an unreasonable voting behaviour. (I mean votes to deletion, not downvotes.)

Comment: @user1551: I was responding to the comment thread *here in this post* being inflammatory, André's comments mostly.

Comment: @gnometorule You stated that the OP would be "subject to a childish vendetta". I wonder if you consider that this is an established fact.

Comment: @Did I do not know about a  "childish vendetta" but from observation I consider it as an established fact that OP is target of continued abuse/bullying on this site (and on MO, to a lesser extent). Ineed, I do not consider this as childish at all anymore but meanwhile as quite severe.

Comment: @Did I think one does have to admit, however, that the OP's questions are subject to vastly higher scrutiny than most other users, and even the good ones tend to be downvoted or closed (and I say this as someone who was voted to close or delete quite a few of the OP's questions, especially on meta).

Comment: @quid Negative feedback, sure. But *abuse*? And *bullying*, even?? I am not convinced.

Comment: @user61527 But regardless of whether your observation is right or wrong, the reason for deletion of an answer should be based on the content of the answer itself, but not the qualities of the poster's questions or answers in the past, or who the poster is.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, I agree completely - my point was that there really are some users who (at least seem) to vote almost reflexively against the OP. I do consider this to be abusive, and tantamount to bullying. My only purpose in the parenthetical was to indicate that there are times when the votes are fair, but that they have exceeded what's reasonable.

Comment: @Did why should the post in question be deleted. I cannot see any intrinsic reason inline with common/generally applied procedures of the site for this.  If there is none it can be an error or abuse. What else? Since it was deleted twice the possibility of  error is pretty small.

Comment: @Did: Vendetta was not a good word, for which I apologize, and different people having opinions about the situation might have reasons of varying degrees of validity. I certainly wasn't thinking of you, say. There are users though who take anything relating OP like a bull seeing a red flag, while being strangely silent (or supportive in the negative) in cases of actual abuse of this site.

Comment: @user1551 Such bullying has occurred for years. It's by far the worst bullying that I have seen in a few decades on the net. It is primarily a small group of users that are at the source of this (e.g. look at the users who often delete MK's Q&A's). In this case there is even one user who voted *twice* to delete that answer (which should not be allowed). I tried to stop this when I was a mod, but that is difficult if not impossible when the users are very close friends with some of the mods. The only way to remedy this is for the community to lobby SE. It is one reason why I resigned as a mod.

Comment: @quid: One word, ten letters. Starts with "soap" ends with "boxing". But seeing how I have absolutely no motivation to explain myself any further (and not because I can't, but because I have actual real life work to do nowadays, and I don't plan on being dragged into pointless meta arguments), I won't go into further details. Let's just say that I'm generally against soapboxing by cranks and I'm against soapboxing by people whom I haven't considered as cranks before writing this comment as well.

Comment: @Bill: Much like how MK complained when his answer was deleted by a moderator, I felt that my vote to delete was overridden by a moderator. I decided to reinstate it, and see if there are non-moderator users who agree with that; and if there are non-moderator users who would vote to undelete. And moreover, I theorize that there is in fact a very small group (roughly four people) who blindly support the OP regardless to what he does, but the rest of the site either don't know or don't like his behavior, but just won't do much because doing things is pointless online.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I *have* agreed with you on numerous actions regarding MK's posts here and on main, and have voted along with you for deletion or closing several times, but I see absolutely no reason to delete this answer. It's on-topic, not disruptive, and civil - it expresses an opinion that I disagree with, but that's not a reason to remove it. It seems of late that voting to close or delete on meta is being used to mean "I *really* disagree."

Comment: @BillDubuque Considering that the answer was unilaterally undeleted by a moderator, I don't see anything wrong with the two normal votes casting second votes for deletion. Their opinions were overridden by a moderator, rendering their votes ineffective.

Comment: @user61527: You're entitled to your opinion. I use my votes to close/delete on meta to express "I don't think this should be on meta at all, because of ..." (and the reasons may vary). I explained my reasons in this case. If there's one thing that I have learned from the past two years is that everyone can do whatever the heck they want on this site, and if they complain enough, people might agree with them for some reason. So I allow myself to act on my beliefs, much like other users feel free to vote to undelete, or do whatever.

Comment: @gnometorule: This has been ground into dust in the meta treadmill. Yes, it's fine to do a lot of things. No it's not fine to do ignore when the community tells you you're doing something wrong, just because it appeared on an SE blog. (And yes, I consider several comments with high vote count, on repeated occasion as "the community".)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yet I don't see any rationale for saying that this answer shouldn't be on meta at all. It contributes something (as do, IMHO, the comments below it), and helps document the community's opinions on the issue being discussed. I think that deleting unpopular but on-topic and meaningful answers is disruptive and harmful.

Comment: @user61527: And I don't see the rationale in believing in after life, vegetarianism, or preferring categorical language over set theoretical language. But these things are rationalized by other people, and I have to live with that. And this concludes my comments on this thread. I will be silently watching and see how the site spirals a little bit closer towards its Eternal September.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much for your support here. If more experienced folks had spoken up when this matter first arose a couple years ago then it probably would never have gotten so far out of hand.  However, I cannot blame anyone who does not wish to become embroiled in the very messy politics of MSE.

Comment: @Asaf Since you said you do not wish to participate further in this comment thread, which is understandable, I will try to answer as short as possible. I consider the reason you give as over-stepping what is within the realm of community moderation and thus as out of line.

Comment: A user asked in a flag "Why have numerous comments been silently deleted from this thread?". A: Because they consisted of speculation about why some user left the site and were not in any way related to the topic.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That is false. For example, some of my comments were deleted that mentioned matters about general policy decisions that are quite relevant to the topic at hand, and quite relevant for users to understand if the site is not going to continue repeating mistakes of the past. That they happened to mention as an example another related topic is no good reason to *censor* the entire discussion. That is outright censorship and should not be tolerated.

Comment: @BillDubuque This thread is not about how much the moderators here suck, illustrated by mentioning unrelated issues. I'm under the expression though that you think every meta thread is on that very topic. If you want, you can make up a new thread and I will repost the comments there in their entirety.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I *highly object* to that comment. I never said anything of that sort and I have no idea why you would make such a remark. It is quite unfair to delete a user's comments then replace them by your own gross misunderstandings of such.

Comment: Someone said it's like bullying a kid in school implying it's not uncommon.
What is uncommon in his analogy is that some(or most) teachers are bullying him or in favor of those who are bullying him.

Comment: A few big comment threads ago, someone commented about "cleaning up meta rather than engaging in endless debates about it" or something like that (the thread had gotten cleaned up, and this comment seems to have gone with it). I only noticed the frequent deletes on meta *after* this incident.

Comment: The "bullying" against Makoto is, IMO, due to a lack of moderation. On other sites, the "bullying" behavior would have been an outright *ban*, and the whole thing would be over and done with. But here, without ♦ moderator action to put an end to things (or conversely, leadership blessing the disputed actions), we're left with the community exercising its moderator powers in the only way it can: downvoting, closing, and deleting the things that it feels are inappropriate.

Comment: @Hurkyl I concur: I feel that there have been serious failures of moderation on both sides of this issue. During the times when MK's posts have violated community norms, the moderators were not quick enough to respond, but rather let the issues consume meta before issuing a suspension. On the other hand, when MK's valid posts have been subject to the abusive behaviour of certain users, the moderators have not acted to prevent these issues either. Considering the *lengthy* history that goes back several years at this point, the moderators should have done something definitive long ago.

Comment: @Hurkyl your comment is quite revealing, in quite a bad way. If you have a probem with the moderatots you should raise that issue in an appropriate way.

Comment: @quid What do you consider to be the appropriate way to address a problem with the moderators, if not in public? These issues have a serious impact on the community.

Comment: I was of course offended by the deletion, but at the same time I was somewhat flattered by it in the corner of my mind. Nobody bothers deleting an answer they don't care about. They do care about my answer.

Comment: @user61527 it can be in public via a dedicated thread or via writing to team for example. To raise the issue in the depth of a comment thread purely to defend abusive behavior is low on various levels.  (In addition writing about "the community" is a bit strong.)

Comment: @quid Fair enough (though I don't see how Hurkyl's comment defends abusive behaviour at all). The reality is that without the ♦-moderators taking definitive action, the issue has just festered for years, and there's a huge amount of bad blood on all sides of this issue.

Comment: @user61527 they wrote about bullying,  under scare quotes I assume, a term I introduced in this discussion thus referencing, and defending, actions I mentioned that are abusive, in my opinion. Frankly, is it really considered normal by some around here to excercise self-justice in some situation because the laws or those enforcing them are not strict enough in this case in ones personal opinion. [And yes I know the site is community moderated, but some things are not in the realm of community moderation, including suspension/ban. And indiscriminate dv and deletions amount to some pseudoban.]

Comment: They(who had been successfuly bullying me) made a big mistake this time by deleting the answer of mine.
I think I know why they dared to do so.
Hint: They knew that I had been suspended because I had opened many meta threads complaining about improper deletions of my questions.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I agree that the underlying problem here is that the moderators have been too slow in handling the underlying issue. I have tried to mention this to them in comments several times, as well. Of course, it is a difficult situation. But indecisiveness has its own penalties, as this thread points out. I don't plan to post in it again. Anyone who prefers to discuss it with me is welcome to do so by email; see my profile for my email address.

Comment: @MakotoKato "I was somewhat flattered by it in the corner of my mind".  Of course, you must have been absolutely delighted by it!

Comment: @ScottH. Just in case you misunderstand me, the deletion was a surprise to me.
I had no intention to seek such delight.

Comment: @user61527 [*During the times when MK's posts have violated community norms,*]
What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @MakotoKato I'm not going to get into yet another discussion about which of your posts have been in violation of community norms - every time I've had this discussion in the past, it's not been at all productive. I will simply mention that the list of questions provided in the moderator notification of your recent suspension is a pretty good start.

Comment: @user61527 [*I will simply mention that the list of questions provided in the moderator notification of your recent suspension is a pretty good start.*]
You don't seem to get the whole picture.
If my questions in the main had not been improperly closed, I would not have created those meta threads. Please notice most of the questions in the main were reopened thanks to those meta threads.

Comment: @MakotoKato I have had literally dozens of discussions with you on meta regarding exactly what aspects of your questions (both on main and meta) I find objectionable. The fact that you continue (as in most other threads) to question me, asking for a specific list of what I object to *after I have clearly told you multiple* tells me that you're not at all interested in hearing what I have to say, and that my time has been completely wasted. I refuse to continue having this discussion with someone who I believe is participating in bad faith.

Answer (score 12):

I deleted your answer in response to a flag asserting that it was made in bad faith, to draw attention to a year-old argument and stir up trouble.  I agreed with that, so I voted to delete, anticipating that there would otherwise be a delete-undelete war that would be disruptive to the community.  (Which, now that my vote has been lifted, there is.)  This is precisely the reason that moderator delete votes are binding.

To those crying out that this was an "abuse of my power," I do *not* apologize for casting a third delete vote to resolve a flag that I agreed with. This has nothing to do with Makoto specifically.  Many similar, heavily downvoted answers to old, controversial questions have been deleted in the past. As a matter of fact, Makoto, I have been a voice in your favor many times.  I have no vendetta against you.  But, you will not make me afraid to do my job.  I have spent many, many hours of my life improving this forum, and I do not take kindly to attempts to disrupt it simply for the sake of doing so.

Lastly, let me briefly respond to André Nicolas.  I will not resign.  I think it's fine that Makoto posted this question, as the decision was perhaps in a grey area, and I have no problem with the answer being undeleted, as that appears to be what the community wants.  But your suggestion, which you admit was aimed to wound me, is something I have taken personally.  I am a kind person, and in my year of moderation, my contributions have made this community a happier, more peaceful place.  I will not be depersonalized.  Show some respect, sir.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of what you wrote in the first paragraph. I see nothing at all "in bad faith" in [MK's answer.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13779/242) Nor do I see anything there that "draws attention to a year old argument". It is the job of a  moderator to *impartially* assess the merits of a (possibly unfounded) flag. If you are not able to do that, then please let someone else handle the flag. And the only reason that this matter is "disruptive to the community" is due to the highly unusual deletion of such an answer - which goes strongly against community norms.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that I upvoted, which seems reasonable to a certain extent. However, it was in my opinion rather clear that there is *also* a risk, and rather a higher one, of causing disruption when deleting it. And while there is a risk in such discussion resurfacing, I do not see that risk being still that high anymore some five days after the answer was given. So, I do not think it was a good decision. But good faith errors in judgement can happen. I will also assume good faith on the side of the flagger, hoping they  might do so the next time as well.

Comment: @BillDubuque The question is a year old about the most controversial topic on meta, and *my impartial judgement* was that the flag was correct.  I don't know what bias you think I have.

Comment: @quid Thanks.  And yes, I acknowledge that the post timing may have been an error on my part.  I didn't notice at the time that the answer was a few days old.

Comment: @Alex The question, though dated, is still highly topical. One might even argue that the success of the site depends crucially on a correct resolution. As such, the more opinions that the community sees on these matters, the more hope there is that we can all understand the motivations behind the various positions, and the more hope we have of reaching an intelligent, reasoned compromise (one that hopefully stops the exodus of teachers). This cannot possibly occur if unpopular answers are *deleted*. Please help keep meta a place where *everyone* can share there thoughts, even those in minority

Comment: @AlexanderGruber My answer was undeleted now. Did you do it?

Comment: @MakotoKato No, I wasn't around for most of the day.  mixedmath undeleted your answer once he saw an appreciable number of people supporting your request (and I support his decision).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber [*(and I support his decision)*]
You thought my answer was made in bad faith and deserved deletion. Have you changed your mind?

Comment: @Bill If Makoto had wanted to bring the topic up again, surely the standard procedure would be to open a new meta thread? I cite Asaf's [answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10635/10513) to a question of Makoto's.

Comment: @user1729PhD: Don't bother citing me. It's like talking about evolution and natural selection with a hardcore creationist.

Comment: @Asaf Perhaps I mean "I cite the upvotes to Asaf's answer..." (the author is -apologies in advance- circumstantial). (Also, I don't think any citation is needed, but I had stumbled across that question earlier and I thought it was relevant. I seem to be having a procrastination-heavy day today though - probably should stop reading old posts...)

Comment: @user1729PhD: Let yourself go once in a Ph.D., take a day off and read old meta "meat grinder topics". It can be fun, in a sadomasochistic kind of way.

Comment: Tempting thought it all sounds - my students have an exam this afternoon and I have not actually checked over it, never mind done the marking scheme...

Comment: @user1729PhD a quick look at your link (I did not study everything in detail) leads me to the conclusion **opposite** to the one you claim. The point there was that Makoto Kato create or wanted to create  **new questions** similar to old ones (there is nothing about answers directly). He was told (in various ways) not to do this in general but only exceptional circumstances. One could get the impression that proper etiquette is indeed to use the old question, and only exceptionally create a new one. Possibly Asaf meant this also to apply to answers to old threads but this is not clear at all

Comment: and him just saying now it was meant  like this would not change the fact that it is generally not clear and thus might have been not clear neither for OP nor for all the people voting. Such strict standards for expressing an opinion on an old topic seem overly extreme, for something with a constant influx of new users and evolving opinions. Anyway to reiterate the key point: your link does IMO not at all support that OP should have known better than to create an answer there, by contrast in view of this thread I would be very heistant to create a new one but rather answer in the old thread.

Comment: @quid Thankyou for your thoughtful comments. However, I disagree with your interpretation, in the sense that the topic in question (problem-statement-questions) count as "exceptional circumstances" and so a new question should be opened (there should be a psq tag!). My "digging up" of a question earlier was on a more minor topic and so would not have required a new question according to my citation (although it was, perhaps, borderline. I don't know. Although I was aware of the hypocrisy when I did it.......)

Comment: @user1729PhD the distinction between high-profile topics and general topics is made in Asaf's answer. Still, the topic there is asking a new question *not* answering old questions. It is thus irrelevant to this discussion. Except for effectively giving the advice of  *not* asking a new question completely opposite to what you claim.

Comment: @user1729PhD There is no "standard procedure" of opening new a meta thread vs. posting an answer in old meta threads. Good arguments can be made on both sides. It most certainly is not "bad faith" to choose one method vs. another. But it is most certainly bad faith to attempt to use this reason as an excuse for blatant longtime bullying of a user.

Comment: @user1729PhD: Called it.

Comment: It's a Q&A platform, not a forum. Stack Exchange is always adamant on making this distinction.